# Numpy `logical_or` for more than two arguments

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Numpy's `logical_or` function takes no more than two arrays to compare.  How can I find the union of more than two arrays?  (The same question could be asked with regard to Numpy's `logical_and` and obtaining the intersection of more than two arrays.)

Comment: [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) ?

Comment: is there a way analagous to any()?

Comment: @user3074893: It's exactly the same issue. You want me to expand my answer?

Answer (score 271):

If you're asking about [`numpy.logical_or`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html), then no, as the docs explicitly say, the only parameters are `x1, x2`, and optionally `out`:

> `numpy.`**`logical_or`**(*`x1, x2[, out]`*) = *`<ufunc 'logical_or'>`*

---

You can of course chain together multiple `logical_or` calls like this:

```
>>> x = np.array([True, True, False, False])
>>> y = np.array([True, False, True, False])
>>> z = np.array([False, False, False, False])
>>> np.logical_or(np.logical_or(x, y), z)
array([ True,  True,  True,  False], dtype=bool)
```

---

The way to generalize this kind of chaining in NumPy is with [`reduce`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html):

```
>>> np.logical_or.reduce((x, y, z))
array([ True,  True,  True,  False], dtype=bool)
```

And of course this will also work if you have one multi-dimensional array instead of separate arrays—in fact, that's how it's *meant* to be used:

```
>>> xyz = np.array((x, y, z))
>>> xyz
array([[ True,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> np.logical_or.reduce(xyz)
array([ True,  True,  True,  False], dtype=bool)
```

But a tuple of three equal-length 1D arrays is an *array_like* in NumPy terms, and can be used as a 2D array.

---

Outside of NumPy, you can also use Python's `reduce`:

```
>>> functools.reduce(np.logical_or, (x, y, z))
array([ True,  True,  True,  False], dtype=bool)
```

However, unlike NumPy's `reduce`, Python's is not often needed. For most cases, there's a simpler way to do things—e.g., to chain together multiple Python `or` operators, don't `reduce` over `operator.or_`, just use `any`. And when there *isn't*, it's usually more readable to use an explicit loop.

And in fact NumPy's [`any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) can be used for this case as well, although it's not quite as trivial; if you don't explicitly give it an axis, you'll end up with a scalar instead of an array. So:

```
>>> np.any((x, y, z), axis=0)
array([ True,  True,  True,  False], dtype=bool)
```

---

As you might expect, [`logical_and`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html#numpy.logical_and) is similar—you can chain it, `np.reduce` it, `functools.reduce` it, or substitute [`all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html) with an explicit `axis`.

What about other operations, like [`logical_xor`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html#numpy.logical_and)? Again, same deal… except that in this case there is no `all`/`any`-type function that applies. (What would you call it? `odd`?)

Comment: `np.logical_or.reduce((x, y, z))` was just what I was looking for!

Comment: ```reduce``` is no longer an internal function in python 3. Instead use: ```functools.reduce()```

Comment: `np.any((x, y, z), axis=0)` is a perfect solution!!!!! I use

Comment: Seems using functools.reduce is faster than numpy's own reduce. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 22):

In case someone still need this - Say you have three Boolean arrays `a`, `b`, `c` with the same shape, this gives `and` element-wise:

```
a * b * c
```

this gives `or`:

```
a + b + c
```

Is this what you want?
Stacking a lot of `logical_and` or `logical_or` is not practical.

Answer (score 12):

Building on abarnert's answer for n-dimensional case:

TL;DR: `np.logical_or.reduce(np.array(list))`

Answer (score 8):

As boolean algebras are both commutative and associative by definition, the following statements or equivalent for **boolean** values of a, b and c.

`a or b or c`

`(a or b) or c`

`a or (b or c)`

`(b or a) or c`

So if you have a "logical_or" which is dyadic and you need to pass it three arguments (a, b, and c), you can call

`logical_or(logical_or(a, b), c)`

`logical_or(a, logical_or(b, c))`

`logical_or(c, logical_or(b, a))`

or whatever permutation you like.

---

Back to python, if you want to test whether a condition (yielded by a function `test` that takes a testee and returns a boolean value) applies to a or b or c or any element of list L, you normally use

```
any(test(x) for x in L)
```

Comment: But Python `or` isn't really boolean `or`, both because it works on values other than `bool`s (returning `a` if `a` is truthy, `b` otherwise), and because it short-circuits (meaning `a or b` may be True, while `b or a` raises an exception).

Comment: @abarnert Thank you, I have edited my answer to account for that.

Comment: (I'm not sure why people downvoted this, however… the OP seems to be specifically talking about boolean values, which he calls "logical conditions".)

Comment: @abarnert Don't ask me. I am of the opinion that if you get your maths straight (in this case boolean algebras) in the background, a lot of programming issues are easier to solve.

Answer (score 7):

I've tried the following three different methods to get the `logical_and` of a list *l* of *k* arrays of size *n*:

1. Using a recursive `numpy.logical_and` (see below)
2. Using `numpy.logical_and.reduce(l)`
3. Using `numpy.vstack(l).all(axis=0)`

Then I did the same for the `logical_or` function. Surprisingly enough, the recursive method is the fastest one.

```
import numpy
import perfplot

def and_recursive(*l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0].astype(bool)
    elif len(l) == 2:
        return numpy.logical_and(l[0],l[1])
    elif len(l) > 2:
        return and_recursive(and_recursive(*l[:2]),and_recursive(*l[2:]))

def or_recursive(*l):
    if len(l) == 1:
        return l[0].astype(bool)
    elif len(l) == 2:
        return numpy.logical_or(l[0],l[1])
    elif len(l) > 2:
        return or_recursive(or_recursive(*l[:2]),or_recursive(*l[2:]))

def and_reduce(*l):
    return numpy.logical_and.reduce(l)

def or_reduce(*l):
    return numpy.logical_or.reduce(l)

def and_stack(*l):
    return numpy.vstack(l).all(axis=0)

def or_stack(*l):
    return numpy.vstack(l).any(axis=0)

k = 10 # number of arrays to be combined

perfplot.plot(
    setup=lambda n: [numpy.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=n) for j in range(k)],
    kernels=[
        lambda l: and_recursive(*l),
        lambda l: and_reduce(*l),
        lambda l: and_stack(*l),
        lambda l: or_recursive(*l),
        lambda l: or_reduce(*l),
        lambda l: or_stack(*l),
    ],
    labels = ['and_recursive', 'and_reduce', 'and_stack', 'or_recursive', 'or_reduce', 'or_stack'],
    n_range=[2 ** j for j in range(20)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    xlabel="len(a)",
    equality_check=None
)
```

Here below the performances for k = 4.

[image: Performances for k=4]

And here below the performances for k = 10.

[image: Performances for k=10]

It seems that there is an approximately constant time overhead also for higher n.

Comment: Try adding `functools.reduce(numpy.logical_and, l)` and `functools.reduce(numpy.logical_or, l)` to your comparison. Interestingly enough, I found them to be actually faster than your recursive implementation for both `k=4` and `k=10`, especially if `len(a) < 10**4`.

Answer (score 6):

I use this workaround which can be extended to n arrays:

```
>>> a = np.array([False, True, False, False])
>>> b = np.array([True, False, False, False])
>>> c = np.array([False, False, False, True])
>>> d = (a + b + c > 0) # That's an "or" between multiple arrays
>>> d
array([ True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 4):

using the sum function:

```
a = np.array([True, False, True])
b = array([ False, False,  True])
c = np.vstack([a,b,b])

Out[172]: 
array([[ True, False,  True],
   [False, False,  True],
   [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

np.sum(c,axis=0)>0
Out[173]: array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
a = np.array([True, False, True])
b = np.array([False, False, True])
c = np.array([True, True, True])
d = np.array([True, True, True])

# logical or
lor = (a+b+c+d).astype(bool)

# logical and
land = (a*b*c*d).astype(bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a short (maybe not optimal) function for performing logical AND on multidimensional boolean masks, you may use this recursive lambda function:

```
masks_and = lambda *masks : masks[0] if len(masks) == 1 else masks_and(np.logical_and(masks[0], masks[-1]), *masks[1:-1])
result = masks_and(mask1, mask2, ...)
```

You can also generalize the lambda function for applying any operator (function of 2 arguments) with distributive property (such as multiplication/AND, sum/OR and so on), assuming the order is also important, to any objects like this:

```
fn2args_reduce = lambda fn2args, *args : args[0] if len(args) == 1 else fn2args_reduce(fn2args, fn2args(args[0], args[1]), *args[2:])
result = fn2args_reduce(np.dot, matrix1, matrix2, ... matrixN)
```

which gives you the same result as if you use `@` numpy operator):

`np.dot(...(np.dot(np.dot(matrix1, matrix2), matrix3)...), matrixN)`

For example `fn2args_reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, 1,2,3,4,5)` gives you 15 - sum of these numbers (of course you have a much more efficient `sum` function for this, but I like it).

Even more generalized model for functions of N arguments could look like this:

```
fnNargs_reduce = lambda fnNargs, N, *args : args[0] if len(args) == 1 else fnNargs_reduce(fnNargs, N, fnNargs(*args[:N]), *args[N:])
fnNargs = lambda x1, x2, x3=neutral, ..., xN=neutral: x1 (?) x2 (?) ... (?) xN
```

Where neutral means it is neutral element for (?) operator, eg. 0 for +, 1 for * etc.

Why? Just for fun :-)