# How to find duplicate words in a line using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is sample jason data.

```
id  opened_date      title       exposure state

1  06/11/2014 9:28 AM Device rebooted and crashed with error 0x024 critical open

2  06/11/2014 7:12 AM Not able to connect to WiFi                  High     open

3  07/23/2014 2:11 PM Sensor failed to recognize movement          Low open

4  07/07/2014 5:20 PM When sensor activated, device rebooted with error 0x024 critical closed
```

I want to write a code with input as a string and output shall point to ID.

For example:

```
Input String = Sensor : Output = ID 3 and 4 has 'Sensor' word in it
Input String = 0x024  : Output = ID 1 and 4 has '0x024' in it.
```

I'm guessing this will require some kind of groupby but it works on complete data set rather than a string. Is this possible with `pandas` or is there any other better solution to analyze this?

Comment: you can do `df.loc[df['title'].str.contains('Sensor'),'id]` so pass your input string as the arg for `str.contains`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting by condition created [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with parameter `case=False`. Last if you need `list` use [`tolist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
li = ['Sensor','0x024']

for i in li:
    print (df.loc[df['title'].str.contains(i, case=False),'id'].tolist())
    [3, 4]
    [1, 4]
```

For storing you can use `dict` comprehension:

```
dfs = { i: df.loc[df['title'].str.contains(i, case=False),'id'].tolist() for i in li }

print (dfs['Sensor'])
[3, 4]
print (dfs['0x024'])
[1, 4]
```

If you need `function`, try `get_id`:

```
def get_id(id):
    ids = df.loc[df['title'].str.contains(id, case=False),'id'].tolist()
    return "Input String = %s : Output = ID " % id + 
            " and ".join(str(x) for x in ids) + 
            " has '%s' in it." % id

print (get_id('Sensor'))
Input String = Sensor : Output = ID 3 and 4 has 'Sensor' in it.

print (get_id('0x024'))
Input String = 0x024 : Output = ID 1 and 4 has '0x024' in it.
```

EDIT by comment:

Now it is more complicated, because use logical `and`:

```
def get_multiple_id(ids):
    #split ids and crete list of boolean series containing each id
    ids1 = [df['title'].str.contains(x, case=False) for x in ids.split()]
    #http://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2901002
    cond = np.logical_and.reduce(ids1)

    ids = df.loc[cond,'id'].tolist()
    return "Input String = '%s' : Output = ID " % id +
           ' and '.join(str(x) for x in ids) +
           " has '%s' in it." % id

print (get_multiple_id('0x024 Sensor'))
Input String = '0x024 Sensor' : Output = ID 4 has '0x024 Sensor' in it.
```

If use logical `or`, it is more easier, because `or` in `re` is `|`, so you can use `0x024|Sensor`:

```
def get_multiple_id(id):
    ids = df.loc[df['title'].str.contains(id.replace(' ','|'), case=False),'id'].tolist()
    return "Input String = '%s' : Output = ID " % id +
            ' and '.join(str(x) for x in ids) +
            " has '%s' in it." % id

print (get_multiple_id('0x024 Sensor'))
Input String = '0x024 Sensor' : Output = ID 1 and 3 and 4 has '0x024 Sensor' in it.
```

Comment: I should have re-framed my question to add one more case. Apologies for asking question in a  comment. How to integrate this use case:  Input String = '0x024, sensor'  : Output = ID 4 has '0x024' and 'sensor' in it.   ?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael . This helped me alot. This is my day2 in Pandas and I am already loving it. Here is next thread I posted: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411300/pandas-split-text-in-column-and-search-in-rows)

Comment: Thank you. But your question is unclear for me. How you can split text? by ` ` or by [ ?

Comment: Or you need common words in ech line?

Comment: Hi jezrael, for selected title, i want to see if any other title in same table has some common words into it. for example, when we submit a new question on stackoverflow, depending on title, we get suggestions of matching issues .

Comment: Ok, so you need find some of strings `[VERY URGENT] Pay your rent` maybe without `[]` in all rows of column `title`? You need find `very` or `urgent` or `pay` or `your` or `rent`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112784/discussion-between-yogi-peace-and-jezrael).