# Pandas- Split text in column and search in rows

Tags: python, pandas

This question is with this history: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37388648/how-to-find-duplicate-words-in-a-line-using-pandas/37388974)

Here is a json format table:

```
ID Title
19 I am doing great
25 [Must fix problem] Stomach not well
31 [Not-so-urgent] Wash cloths
498 [VERY URGENT] Pay your rent
517 Landlord wants you to pay your rent tomorrow
918 Girlfriend wants to help you to pay rent if you take her out
1000 [Always reproducible issue] Room partner dont want to pay any rent, he is out of cash
```

I did this

In:
    selected_row_title = df.loc[df['id'] == 4]["title"]

Output:

```
[VERY URGENT] Pay your rent
```

Now, by using Python Pandas, I am trying to write a function as:

```
get_matching_rows(selected_row_title )
```

Output

```
ID 498 has pay your rent 
ID 517 has pay your rent
ID 918 has pay rent
ID 1000 has pay rent
```

I have been tearing my hair out on this and I really need some help, atleast a guidance on how once can implement this. Appreciate any inputs.

Comment: Am I right to assume that you want to select all the rows that have "pay rent" in "Title" column? The description seems little bit unclear to me.

Comment: yes, select all rows that have 'pay rent' common in 'title'. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
s = "[VERY URGENT] Pay your rent"

#replace all [] in column title
tit = df.Title.str.replace(r'[\[\]]', '')
print (tit)

0                                     I am doing great
1                    Must fix problem Stomach not well
2                            Not-so-urgent Wash cloths
3                            VERY URGENT Pay your rent
4         Landlord wants you to pay your rent tomorrow
5    Girlfriend wants to help you to pay rent if yo...
6    Always reproducible issue Room partner dont wa...
Name: Title, dtype: object

#search one of word of string s (logical or is |)
mask = tit.str.contains(s.replace(' ', '|'))
print (mask)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6     True
Name: Title, dtype: bool
```

```
#select all ID by condition
selected_row_title = df.loc[mask, 'ID']
print (selected_row_title)
2      31
3     498
4     517
5     918
6    1000
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```