# Elementwise AND or OR operations in python for 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, logical-operators

Is there any method in python to compute elementwise OR or AND operations for 2D arrays across rows or columns?

For example, for the following array, elementwise OR operations across row would result in a vector `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Yes: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/3923281), specifically the details about the `.reduce` method of ufuncs.

Comment: You may use `numpy.apply_along_axis()` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html

Answer (score 8):

numpy has `logical_or`, `logical_xor` and `logical_and` which have a `reduce` method

```
>> np.logical_or.reduce(a, axis=0)
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

as you see in the example they coerce to `bool` dtype, so if you require `uint8` you have to cast back in the end.

since bools are stored as bytes you can use cheap viewcasting for that.

with the `axis` keyword you can select *along* which axis to reduce. it is possible to select multiple axes

```
>> np.logical_or.reduce(a, axis=1)
array([ True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> np.logical_or.reduce(a, axis=(0, 1))
True
```

the `keepdims` keyword is useful for broadcasting, for example to find all "crosses" of rows and columns >= 2 in array `b`

```
>>> b = np.random.randint(0,10, (4, 4))
>>> b
array([[0, 5, 3, 4],
       [4, 1, 5, 4],
       [4, 5, 5, 5],
       [2, 4, 6, 1]])
>>> rows = np.logical_and.reduce(b >= 2, axis=1, keepdims=True)
# keepdims=False (default) -> rows.shape==(4,)  keepdims=True -> rows.shape==(4, 1)
>>> cols = np.logical_and.reduce(b >= 2, axis=0, keepdims=True)
# keepdims=False (default) -> cols.shape==(4,)  keepdims=True -> cols.shape==(1, 4)
>>> rows & cols # shapes (4, 1) and (1, 4) are broadcast to (4, 4)
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

notice the slight abuse of the `&` operator which stands for `bitwise_and`. since the effect is the same on bools (in fact trying to use `and` in this place would have thrown an exception) this is common practice

as @ajcr points out the popular `np.any` and `np.all` are shorthand for `np.logical_or.reduce` and `np.logical_and.reduce`.
note, however, that there are subtle differences

```
>>> np.logical_or.reduce(a)
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> np.any(a)
True
```

OR:

if you want to stick with `uint8` and know for certain all your entries will be 0 and 1 you can use `bitwise_and`, `bitwise_or` and `bitwise_xor`

```
>>> np.bitwise_or.reduce(a, axis=0)
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: For the OP's particular `and`/`or` case, it might also be worth noting that `logical_or.reduce` is just equivalent to `np.any` or `ndarray.any`, and that the `logical_and.reduce` is exactly the same as `np.all` or `ndarray.all` (this is how they are defined in the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/f737b354e6ab2aef8b4c05bca0011de46a4b53b0/numpy/core/_methods.py#L20-L21)).