# How to map sevaral keywords with a dataframe column values using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains, data-analysis

Hi I have a list of keywords.

```
keyword_list=['one','two']

DF,

    Name      Description
    Sri       Sri is one of the good singer in this two
    Ram       Ram is one of the good cricket player
```

I want to find the rows which are having all the values from my keyword_list.

my desired output is,

```
output_Df,
    Name    Description
    Sri     Sri is one of the good singer in this two

I tried, mask=DF['Description'].str.contains() method but I can do this only for a single word pls help.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [np.logical_and + reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2901002) of all masks created by `list comprehension`:

```
keyword_list=['one','two']

m = np.logical_and.reduce([df['Description'].str.contains(x) for x in keyword_list])
df1 = df[m]
print (df1)

  Name                                Description
0  Sri  Sri is one of the good singer in this two
```

Alternatives for mask:

```
m = np.all([df['Description'].str.contains(x) for x in keyword_list], axis=0)

#if no NaNs
m = [set(x.split()) >= set(keyword_list) for x in df['Description']]
```

Comment: your solution for the above question is working fine, could you please suggest me best tutorials for numpy and pandas as I want to be good with it.

Comment: Hard question, in my opinion the best are pandas documentation and tutorials, especially I like [modern pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#modern-pandas).

Comment: I did. I was told to wait for sometime to accept it.