# Filter out according to specific multiple conditions in pandas

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataframe that I read from csv file:

```
   gene name  annotation  ng DNA
 0  HRAS       G12S        3.00
 1  PIK3CA     R88L        3.00
 2  BRAF       E474A       3.00
 3  EGFR       E734Q       3.00
 4  EGFR       V769        3.00
 5  BRAF       LQ599PE     4.00
 6  BRAF       KT587NA     4.00
 7  HRAS       G12S        17.70
```

I'd like to filter according to multiple conditions in 2 columns:
for example to filter according to 'BRAF' + 'E474A' and 'HRAS'+ 'G12S', so the following df will be created:

```
   gene name  annotation  ng DNA
 0  HRAS       G12S        3.00
 2  BRAF       E474A       3.00
 7  HRAS       G12S        17.70
```

Any ideas for an elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and for join all masks to one by [`np.logical_or.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2901002):

```
m1 = (df['gene name'] == 'BRAF') & (df['annotation'] == 'E474A')
m2 = (df['gene name'] == 'HRAS') & (df['annotation'] == 'G12S')

df = df[np.logical_or.reduce([m1, m2])]
print (df)
  gene name annotation  ng DNA
0      HRAS       G12S     3.0
2      BRAF      E474A     3.0
7      HRAS       G12S    17.7
```

More dynamic solution with list of tuples for values for filter in `list comprehension`:

```
tup = [('BRAF','E474A'), ('HRAS', 'G12S')]
df = df[np.logical_or.reduce([(df['gene name']== a)&(df['annotation']== b) for a, b in tup])]
print (df)
  gene name annotation  ng DNA
0      HRAS       G12S     3.0
2      BRAF      E474A     3.0
7      HRAS       G12S    17.7
```

Comment: Do you know how to merge 2 columns into 1? I'd like to merge the 'gene name' column with 'annotation'

Comment: You can use `df['merged'] = df['gene name'] + ' - ' + df['annotation']`

Comment: Tried it already, didn't work. Gave me the following warning message: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: OK, it is another problem. You need `copy()` like `df1 = df[np.logical_or.reduce([m1, m2])].copy()` - if you modify values in `df` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df1`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: @Bella - Glad can help you!