# Select Pandas rows with regex match

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have the following data-frame.

[image]

and I have an input list of values

[image]

I want to match each item from the input list  to the Symbol and Synonym column in the data-frame and to extract only those rows where the input value appears in either the Symbol column or Synonym column(Please note that here the values are separated by '|' symbol).

In the output data-frame I need an additional column Input_symbol which denotes the matching value. So here in this case the desired output will should be like the image bellow.

How can I do the same ?.

[image]

Comment: Why is `A2MP1` excluded in output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has changed. What you want to do now is to look through the two columns (Symbol and Synonyms) and if you find a value that is inside `mylist` return it. If no match you can return 'No match!' (for instance).

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = '''\
Symbol,Synonyms
A1BG,A1B|ABG|GAB|HYST2477
A2M,A2MD|CPAMD5|FWP007|S863-7
A2MP1,A2MP
NAT1,AAC1|MNAT|NAT-1|NATI
NAT2,AAC2|NAT-2|PNAT
NATP,AACP|NATP1
SERPINA3,AACT|ACT|GIG24|GIG25'''

mylist = ['GAB', 'A2M', 'GIG24']
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))

# Store the lookup serie
lookup_serie = df['Symbol'].str.cat(df['Synonyms'],'|').str.split('|')

# Create lambda function to return first value from mylist, No match! if stop-iteration
f = lambda x: next((i for i in x if i in mylist), 'No match!')

df.insert(0,'Input_Symbol',lookup_serie.apply(f))
print(df)
```

Returns

```
  Input_Symbol    Symbol                   Synonyms
0          GAB      A1BG       A1B|ABG|GAB|HYST2477
1          A2M       A2M  A2MD|CPAMD5|FWP007|S863-7
2    No match!     A2MP1                       A2MP
3    No match!      NAT1       AAC1|MNAT|NAT-1|NATI
4    No match!      NAT2            AAC2|NAT-2|PNAT
5    No match!      NATP                 AACP|NATP1
6        GIG24  SERPINA3       AACT|ACT|GIG24|GIG25
```

---

**Old solution:**

```
f = lambda x: [i for i in x.split('|') if i in mylist] != []

m1 = df['Symbol'].apply(f)
m2 = df['Synonyms'].apply(f)

df[m1 | m2]
```

Comment: @jezrael What do you think about this? I am not sure how I can make the lookup_serie more readable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This almost solves my problem. A slight change can be since my actual data-frame is around 60,100 rows and input list has around 9000 items, is there a way we can make it bit more time efficient?. Also I don't need the no matching rows. Would that make it more time efficient ?

Comment: @SAJILCK Yeah well you can change it to `None` or maybe `''` but shouldn't give you a big boost. I can't think of something that would speed it up unfortunately.

Comment: @AntonvBR - Not sure if possible boost it. In my opinion `regex` solution should failed, because too many values.

Answer (score 3):

IIUIC, use

```
In [346]: df[df.Synonyms.str.contains('|'.join(mylist))]
Out[346]:
     Symbol                   Synonyms
0      A1BG       A1B|ABG|GAB|HYST2477
1       A2M  A2MD|CPAMD5|FWP007|S863-7
2     A2MP1                       A2MP
6  SERPINA3       AACT|ACT|GIG24|GIG25
```

Comment: OP need `I want to extract only those rows from the data-frame where the strings in mylist appears in Symbol column or Synonym column(here it is separated by '|' symbol).` - so is necessary check both columns :(

Answer (score 3):

Check in both columns by [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and chain conditions by `|` (or), last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mylist = ['GAB', 'A2M', 'GIG24']
m1 = df.Synonyms.str.contains('|'.join(mylist))
m2 = df.Symbol.str.contains('|'.join(mylist))

df = df[m1 | m2]
```

Another solution is [`logical_or.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2901002) all masks created by `list comprehension`:

```
masks = [df[x].str.contains('|'.join(mylist)) for x in ['Symbol','Synonyms']]
m = np.logical_or.reduce(masks)
```

Or by [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), then use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at least one `True` per row:

```
m = df[['Symbol','Synonyms']].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('|'.join(mylist))).any(1)
```

---

```
df = df[m]

print (df)
     Symbol                   Synonyms
0      A1BG       A1B|ABG|GAB|HYST2477
1       A2M  A2MD|CPAMD5|FWP007|S863-7
2     A2MP1                       A2MP
6  SERPINA3       AACT|ACT|GIG24|GIG25
```