# pd._to_datetime() convert time only

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Is there any way to use `pd.to_datetime()` to convert string in *H:M:S* to time only?

When I use `pd.to_datetime()`, it give me `01/01/1900  09:08:20`.

And subsequently, I want to compute `deltaT = endTime - beginTime`. Can I just subtract the time elements?

Comment: You can use [pandas.Series.dt.time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.time.html) attribute to get time. `pd.to_datetime(df, format='%H:%M:%S').dt.time` like this. And you can just subtract the columns to find the timedelta. Or do something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22924683/826970). Can you edit in a sample input and expected output to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think not.

But you can convert both columns to datetime and then get difference. Dates are some so get difference of times only. Last you can convert difference to seconds by [`seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.seconds.html) or [`total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) if possible `time1 < time2`:

```
df['diff'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['time1']) - 
              pd.to_datetime(df['time2']))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time1':['09:08:20','09:20:20','19:08:20'],
                   'time2':['09:07:20','09:20:20','19:08:10']})

print (df)
      time1     time2
0  09:08:20  09:07:20
1  09:20:20  09:20:20
2  19:08:20  19:08:10

df['diff'] = abs(pd.to_datetime(df['time1']) - 
              pd.to_datetime(df['time2'])).dt.seconds

print (df)

      time1     time2  diff
0  09:08:20  09:07:20    60
1  09:20:20  09:20:20     0
2  19:08:20  19:08:10    10
```

Comment: Yep I also think you need to include full daettime to handle time. +1Specifying format is not necessary in this case.

Comment: @AntonvBR - Thank you. Just one thing, OP yesterday change [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48865605/2901002), I think you can edited answer ;)

Comment: @AntonvBR - Thank you, I test it and it working for positive timedelta very nice. But for negative timedeltas seems better is `total_seconds`.

Comment: @AntonvBR - It depends of data, so I think solution now is OK ;)

Comment: added abs() before. SO is slow for my part and I'm going on lunch. I'll look at the linked question soon.

Comment: @AntonvBR - I want ask it, today is SO totaly broken for me too.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `datetime` module, first strip your time using `strptime()` and then rebuilt it with the `strftime()`:

```
import datetime
time = "2017-10-16T08:27:16+0000"
stripedTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S%z')

newTime = stripedTime.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print(newTime)
```