# Apply a list of filters to a dataframe coming from a list using pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a list of columns to apply filters in a dataframe which comes from a list. The filter values comes from another list.

Earlier when the lists were of fixed, I used the following statement to get the job done:

```
df_result= df[(df[filterfieldList[0]] == filterValuesList[0]) & (df[filterfieldList[1]] == filterValuesList[1]) & (df[filterfieldList[2]] == filterValuesList[2])]
```

But as the weeks progressed I get a new requirement that the filtering list would be dynamic and I couldn't figure out how to do that now. As in, sometimes, the filters list will have only 2 fields to filter, sometime 3 or 5.
How to do the filtering in this situation?

Sample Data:

```
A             B            C                   D                 E
Project 1        Org_1     Directory        MSTR           Configuration    
Project 1        Org_1     Directory        MSTR          Unable to Login
Project 1       Org_1   Desktop Software    MSTR             Configuration
Project 1      Org_1    Desktop Software    MSTR           Configuration]
Project 1      Org_1    Directory           MSTR          Unable to Login
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Sure, Adding it now. Please check out the the question description at the end.

Comment: Or modify my sample DataFrame :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think need list comprehension for create `mask`s and then [`np.logical_and.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20528328/2901002) for reduce and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
filterfieldList = ['A','B','E']
filterValuesList = ['Project 1', 'Org_1', 'Unable to Login']

tups = zip(filterfieldList, filterValuesList)
df_result = df[np.logical_and.reduce([(df[i] == j) for i, j in tups])]
print (df_result)
           A      B          C     D                E
1  Project 1  Org_1  Directory  MSTR  Unable to Login
4  Project 1  Org_1  Directory  MSTR  Unable to Login
```

EDIT:

If need combine multiple filters per rows:

```
filterfieldList = ['A','B','E', 'E']
filterValuesList = ['Project 1', 'Org_1', 'Unable to Login', 'Configuration']

f = pd.DataFrame({'field': filterfieldList, 'val':filterValuesList})
f = f.groupby('field')['val'].apply(list)
print (f)
field
A                         [Project 1]
B                             [Org_1]
E    [Unable to Login, Configuration]
Name: val, dtype: object

df_result = df[np.logical_and.reduce([(df[i].isin(j)) for i, j in f.items()])]
print (df_result)
           A      B                 C     D                E
0  Project 1  Org_1         Directory  MSTR    Configuration
1  Project 1  Org_1         Directory  MSTR  Unable to Login
2  Project 1  Org_1  Desktop Software  MSTR    Configuration
4  Project 1  Org_1         Directory  MSTR  Unable to Login
```

Comment: @MukulSharma - Super :)

Comment: is "np" in your code "df[np.logical_and.reduce([(df[i] == j) for i, j in tups])]" is numpy? or does that stand for anything else?

Comment: be free use `pd.np` or add `import numpy as np`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got great results :)

Comment: @ManikanthaNekkalapudi - Glad can help!

Comment: This works great on the when the lists contain the filters for each cloumn. But, There are some scenarios where each column have multiple filters. Example: Column 'E' has two filters 'Unable to Login' and 'Configuration'. The above solutions happens to fail under this scenario... How to over come this particular case?

Comment: @ManikanthaNekkalapudi - How looks `filterValuesList` ?

Comment: @ManikanthaNekkalapudi - this is something like `filterValuesList = ['Project 1', 'Org_1', 'Unable to Login|Configuration']` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167408/discussion-between-manikantha-nekkalapudi-and-jezrael).

Comment: No. All the filter values happens to be in list like in the list format as below:
filterValuesList = ['Project 1', 'Org_1', 'Unable to Login', 'Configuration']

Comment: And `filterfieldList = ['A','B','E', 'E']` ? Then it should working nice, no change necessary.

Comment: I'm not getting results when I used the above example!

Comment: So it doeas not work if `filterValuesList = ['Project 1', 'Org_1', 'Unable to Login', 'Configuration']` and `filterfieldList = ['A','B','E', 'E']` ? in second list is `E` twice.

Comment: Yes, I saw the dataframe after filtering the columns A,B,E. It's working as expected but the second time filtering on column 'E' is being applied on the filtered result of columns A,B,E. So, I'm not able to get the data when there are two filters for the same field in a dataframe.

Comment: @ManikanthaNekkalapudi - Yes, there is problem different length of both lists. But not sure how general solution should working.

Comment: list lengths are always same as you mentioned them in you previous comment.

filterfieldList = ['A','B','E', 'E']

 filterValuesList = ['Project 1', 'Org_1', 'Unable to Login', 'Configuration']

Comment: @ManikanthaNekkalapudi - I understand now.

Comment: Once again I'm here to thank you for all the efforts you put in to answer my question and I'm really glad to say that everything works pitch perfect. Thanks very much! :)

Comment: @ManikanthaNekkalapudi - You are welcome! And nice weekend!

Comment: This technique comes in pretty handy when going over groupby keys to compare/modify between two different independent dataframes of similar, yet different data.  It can be done without it, but this way is re-usable, clean, and simple!  My use case is probably outside the expected normal use of the Pandas library to control an application and track the changes in data along its processing route.