# Filtering the comma separated values in multiple columns in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

This is the example dataframe that I am working:

```
df:

a      b     c
a1  P1,P3  abc
a2  P2,P4  def
a3  P2     ghi   `
```

I want to apply filters on multiple columns in a dataframe which has comma separated values in them.

Filter data is in the form of a `series` named as `df_filters` mentioned below:

```
df_filters:
a    [a1]
b    [P1, P4]`
```

The filter data contains dataframe `column name` as a `string` in first column and `filter values` as `list` in second column.

Using the above `df_filters` filter the dataframe `df1` and get the following result:

```
Result1:
a      b     c
a1  P1,P3  abc
a2  P2,P4  def  `
```

Conclusion: for column `a` in `df1` consider only those rows with value `a1` and for column `b` consider only those rows which contains values `P1` and `P4`. In column `b` row 1, `P1` and `P3` are two different values with comma separation.

Is there anyway I can achieve the above `Result` for `df`?

for reference to the similar scenario, kindly look into the following link:
[Apply a list of filters to a dataframe coming from a list using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49444787/apply-a-list-of-filters-to-a-dataframe-coming-from-a-list-using-pandas)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you elaborate and write concisely what's the question and what is expected output

Comment: @min2bro: I've edited the question and included all the necessary information

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df_filters = pd.Series([['a1'], ['P1', 'P4'],['s']], index=['a','b','z'])
print (df_filters)
a        [a1]
b    [P1, P4]
z         [s]
dtype: object

#filter only matched columns
df_filters = df_filters.loc[df_filters.index.intersection(df.columns)]

#convert to set and get intersection of each value
from itertools import repeat
m = [[bool(set(a.split(',')).intersection(b)) for a, b in zip(df[i], repeat(j))] 
      for i, j in df_filters.items()]
print (m)
[[True, False, False], [True, True, False]]

#flatten boolean masks and filter
df = df[pd.np.logical_or.reduce(m)]
print (df)
    a      b    c
0  a1  P1,P3  abc
1  a2  P2,P4  def
```

Comment: Hey @jezrael, Thanks for your answer. I'll try it today and let you know. You know what, the old solution that you answered (mentioned a ref. link in this question) is working fine after posting this question. I blame VS Code for this error!

Answer (score 0):

For each value you are checking if it exists in the corresponding `df_filters` list. Since the column can contain a list or individual item it needs to check for this as well.
Since this condition is a bit complex, i moved this logic to separate function `_filter_func`.

```
def _filter_func(x, f_vals_set):
    if not isinstance(x, list):
        # This is needed becouse values in dataframe could be single object or a list of objects
        x = [x]
    # Check if the there is any matching value in filter set
    matching_vals = f_vals_set.intersection(x)
    return len(matching_vals) > 0

conditions = [df[col].apply(lambda x: _filter_func(x, set(f_vals))) for col, f_vals in filters.items()]
df.loc[pd.np.logical_or.reduce(conditions)]
```

Comment: Hey @shanmuga, Thanks for answering. I'm not able to understand you solution clearly but I tried to use it and couldn't get the required result.