# np.where index is greater than a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I assumed this would be fairly straight-forward, but apparently I'm missing something here.

I want to be able to utilize `np.where` with `df.groupby('Name').apply()` to create a new column in `df` (call it `'New'`), where the values of the column are `1` if the indices of the respective group (indices corresponding to the original `df`) are greater than or equal to (`>=`) a particular value, else `0`.

For background, I am grouping `df` by the `'Name'` column and I have a `dict()` that contains the corresponding value to use for each name from the `groupby()`. I hope that is clear, I can provide further clarification if necessary.

Here is what I have so far, given sample `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['William', 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],['James', 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],['James', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                ['James', 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],['William', 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],['William', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                ['William', 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],['James', 0, 1, 1, 0, 1],['James', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
                columns=['Name','x1','x2','x3','x4','Interest'])

       Name  x1  x2  x3  x4  Interest
0  William   1   0   0   0         1
1    James   0   1   1   1         1
2    James   1   0   0   0         0
3    James   1   0   1   1         0
4  William   0   1   1   0         1
5  William   0   0   0   0         0
6  William   1   0   1   1         0
7    James   0   1   1   0         1
8    James   0   0   0   0         0
```

Then I am finding the last row in `df` for each group where the `'Interest'` column has a `1`, using:

```
mydict = df[df['Interest']==1].groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x.index[-1]).to_dict()

{'James': 7, 'William': 4}
```

Note: This is a simplified example. For my actual application, I am pulling the index of the 3rd to last row (i.e. `.apply(lambda x: x.index[-3]).to_dict()`), however the next part is where the root of my question lies.

Now, I want to create a new column `'Name'`, where the value is `1` if the row index is `>=` the value in `mydict` for that group, else `0`. I've tried a few things:

```
for key, val in mydict.items():
    df['New'] = np.where((df['Name']==key) & (df.index>=val), 1, 0)
```

This obviously will override anything done for `'James'` and just return the correct column for `'William'`. How can I efficiently do this?

To be thorough, here is my expected output:

```
      Name  x1  x2  x3  x4  Interest  New
0  William   1   0   0   0         1    0
1    James   0   1   1   1         1    0
2    James   1   0   0   0         0    0
3    James   1   0   1   1         0    0
4  William   0   1   1   0         1    1
5  William   0   0   0   0         0    1
6  William   1   0   1   1         0    1
7    James   0   1   1   0         1    1
8    James   0   0   0   0         0    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map`

```
df.assign(New=(df.index >= df.Name.map(mydict)).astype(int))

      Name  x1  x2  x3  x4  Interest  New
0  William   1   0   0   0         1    0
1    James   0   1   1   1         1    0
2    James   1   0   0   0         0    0
3    James   1   0   1   1         0    0
4  William   0   1   1   0         1    1
5  William   0   0   0   0         0    1
6  William   1   0   1   1         0    1
7    James   0   1   1   0         1    1
8    James   0   0   0   0         0    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension for all masks and then [reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20528328) them to one, last convert it to integer - `True`s are `1`s:

```
m = [((df['Name']==key) & (df.index>=val)) for key, val in mydict.items()]
print (m)
[0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6    False
7     True
8     True
Name: Name, dtype: bool, 0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7    False
8    False
Name: Name, dtype: bool]

df['New'] = np.logical_or.reduce(m).astype(int)
print (df)
      Name  x1  x2  x3  x4  Interest  New
0  William   1   0   0   0         1    0
1    James   0   1   1   1         1    0
2    James   1   0   0   0         0    0
3    James   1   0   1   1         0    0
4  William   0   1   1   0         1    1
5  William   0   0   0   0         0    1
6  William   1   0   1   1         0    1
7    James   0   1   1   0         1    1
8    James   0   0   0   0         0    1
```

EDIT:

Another solution for this problem:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 2, ignore_index=True)
```

Get index of first True value per condition - count 3rd value from back

```
idx = df[df['Interest']==1].groupby('Name').cumcount(ascending=False).eq(2).idxmax()
```

Set values from idx to end to 1:

```
df['New'] = 0
df.loc[idx:, 'New'] = 1
print (df)
       Name  x1  x2  x3  x4  Interest  New
0   William   1   0   0   0         1    0
1     James   0   1   1   1         1    0
2     James   1   0   0   0         0    0
3     James   1   0   1   1         0    0
4   William   0   1   1   0         1    1
5   William   0   0   0   0         0    1
6   William   1   0   1   1         0    1
7     James   0   1   1   0         1    1
8     James   0   0   0   0         0    1
9   William   1   0   0   0         1    1
10    James   0   1   1   1         1    1
11    James   1   0   0   0         0    1
12    James   1   0   1   1         0    1
13  William   0   1   1   0         1    1
14  William   0   0   0   0         0    1
15  William   1   0   1   1         0    1
16    James   0   1   1   0         1    1
17    James   0   0   0   0         0    1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df[df['Interest']==1].groupby('Name').cumcount(ascending=False))
0     3
1     3
4     2
7     2
9     1
10    1
13    0
16    0
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This solution worked just as I needed, however the solution from @piRSquared avoids the need for the list comprehension. I truly appreciate your answer, thanks!

Comment: @rahlf23 - I find beter solution, please check edited answer. Only need index of first True value.