# How to filter a Pandas DataFrame using multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a data frame object as below

```
    Issue Type       Status  Reporter  Issue id
0   Eng Activity       Closed  snalanag     98908
1   Eng Activity  In Progress  snalanag     98452
2   Eng Activity       Closed  snalanag     98425
3     Dev-Defect       Closed  snalanag     97244
4     Dev-Defect       Closed  snalanag     96716
5   Eng Activity       Closed  snalanag     96698
6     Dev-Defect       Closed  snalanag     96696
```

Now i want to filter data based on multiple conditions.

Condition will be in dictionary. 
Example:`{'Issue Type': 'Dev-Defect', 'Status': 'Closed', 'Reporter': 'snalanag'}`

Based on the condition, i have to filter the data frame by forming the query dynamically. Please note that i need to filter the data by applying `AND` condition .

That means i have to apply the filter for the given data frame with `"Issue Type = Dev-Defect","Status = Closed","Reporter = snalanag"` at once.

Something like this but it should be generated dynamically based on the condition dictionary.

print (df[(df["Issue key"] == 'BUG-22212') & (df["Issue id"] == 97244) & (df["Status"] == 'Closed')])

Comment: Post sample data *in your question*

Comment: Added the sample data. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.loc` with `numpy.logical_and` in it to accommodate multiple logical expressions. Since `numpy.logical_and` can have only 2 expressions, `reduce` function can be used to make it work with multiple expressions. An explanation: [Numpy `logical_or` for more than two arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528328/numpy-logical-or-for-more-than-two-arguments).

For your case we can use something like:

```
df.loc[np.logical_and.reduce((df["Issue Type"]=="Dev-Defect", df["Status"]=="Closed", df["Reporter"]=="snalanag"))]
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Since you are using a dictionary for conditions, following may help:

```
conditions = {'Issue Type': 'Dev-Defect', 'Status': 'Closed', 'Reporter': 'snalanag'}
df.loc[np.logical_and.reduce(list(map(lambda x: df[x]==conditions[x], conditions.keys())))]
```

Comment: Hi Dhanush, your logic is working. if i write your condition manually::: print (df.loc[np.logical_and.reduce((df["Issue Type"]=="Dev-Defect", df["Status"]=="Closed", df["Reporter"]=="snalanag"))]). But i want the condition to be generated dynamically based on the condition dictionary length. I can't hardcode the values of condition inside syntax

Comment: @SivaSaiKumarNalanagula I have edited the answer to use a dictionary of conditions instead of hardcoded values. See whether it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Dhanush. It helped and working fine. Once again thanks for helping in time.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get away with something like this:

```
cond_dict = {'Issue Type': 'Dev-Defect', 'Status': 'Closed', 'Reporter': 'snalanag'}

final_mask = np.ones(len(orig_df)).astype(bool)

for this_cond in cond_dict:
    cond_dict = (final_mask ) & (orig_df[this_cond] == cond_dict[this_cond])

filtered_df = orig_df[final_mask]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code. But it is getting failed due to invalid comparison of dtype object. Getting exception "cannot compare a dtyped [bool] array with a scalar of type [bool]"

Comment: There, I've made a small change. See if that helps! And if so, please consider marking the question as answered =)

Comment: This didn't help. why because not all the columns are of same dtype. Some are object,some are bool, some are int64. But i wanted to get the filtered data after applying condition. My condition should be something like this:: print (df[(df["Issue Type"] == 'Dev-Defect') & (df["Issue id"] == 97244)]). Same condition i want to generate dynamically based on the condition dicctionary