# Combine list of list of booleans based on AND or OR condition

Tags: python, list, boolean

For combining two lists of booleans based on OR, `np.logical_or` can be used, and similarity AND can be done with `np.logical_and`.

However, if I have a list of 10 lists of boolean values and want to combine them using either AND or OR, I cannot find an easy way to do this.

Could you please suggest the most efficient way?

EDIT:

```
booleans = [[True, True, False, True, False], [True, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False]]
```

OR output: `[True, True, False, True, False]`

AND output: `[True, False, False, False, False]`

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: can you add an example of input -> output?

Comment: What do you mean by combining lists here?

Comment: Should the implementation use `numpy`?

Comment: If you're want a NumPy array as output, use `numpy.logical_and.reduce` -  or more generally [`ufunc.reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy \`logical\_or\` for more than two arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528328/numpy-logical-or-for-more-than-two-arguments)

Comment: @miradulo @jfowkes If I do that, I get an error `TypeError: Internal Numpy error: too many arguments in call to PyUFunc_HasOverride`. I am combining around 500 of these boolean lists with or operator (`np.logical_or.reduce(*list_)`)

Comment: @JackArnestad Don't unpack the list in your call. Also, is your intent indeed to use NumPy here?

Comment: I commented because if OP is using NumPy this is a many-times-over duplicate. `np.any` and `np.all` are accomplishing the same thing as well.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution without numpy

```
>>> booleans = [[True, True, False, True, False], [True, False, False, False, False], [True, False, False, False, False]]
>>> or_output = list(map(any, zip(*booleans)))
>>> and_output = list(map(all, zip(*booleans)))
>>> 
>>> print (or_output)
[True, True, False, True, False]
>>> print (and_output)
[True, False, False, False, False]
>>>
```

Comment: Bonus if you can show how you're just passing a function `f` into the surrounding structure of the `map`.

Comment: @wheaties This solution also zips the list twice, when it can easily be done once.

Comment: @RoadRunner From the question "_using either AND or OR_" - doing both at once doesn't seem necessary.