# Pandas filtering with datetime index

Tags: python, pandas

With a datetime index to a Pandas dataframe, it is easy to get a range of dates:

```
df[datetime(2018,1,1):datetime(2018,1,10)]
```

Filtering is straightforward too:

```
df[ (df['column A'] = 'Done') & (df['column B'] < 3.14 )]
```

But what is the best way to simultaneously filter by range of dates and any other non-date criteria?

Answer (score 26):

#### 3 boolean conditions

```
c0 = df.index.to_series().between('2018-01-01', '2018-01-10')
c1 = df['column A'] == 'Done'
c2 = df['column B'] < 3.14

df[c0 & c1 & c2]

           column A  column B
2018-01-04     Done  2.533385
2018-01-06     Done  2.789072
2018-01-08     Done  2.230017
```

#### Setup

```
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column A': ['Done', 'Not Done'] * 10,
    'column B': np.random.randn(20) + np.pi
}, pd.date_range('2017-12-25', periods=20))

df

            column A  column B
2017-12-25      Done  1.011868
2017-12-26  Not Done  1.873127
2017-12-27      Done  1.171093
2017-12-28  Not Done  0.882538
2017-12-29      Done  2.792306
2017-12-30  Not Done  3.114638
2017-12-31      Done  3.457829
2018-01-01  Not Done  3.490375
2018-01-02      Done  3.856957
2018-01-03  Not Done  3.912356
2018-01-04      Done  2.533385
2018-01-05  Not Done  3.493983
2018-01-06      Done  2.789072
2018-01-07  Not Done  2.725724
2018-01-08      Done  2.230017
2018-01-09  Not Done  2.999055
2018-01-10      Done  3.888432
2018-01-11  Not Done  1.637436
2018-01-12      Done  3.752955
2018-01-13  Not Done  3.541812
```

Answer (score 8):

If there is multiple boolean masks is possible use [`np.logical_and.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20528328):

```
m1 = df.index > '2018-01-01'
m2 = df.index < '2018-01-10'
m3 = df['column A'] == 'Done'
m4 = df['column B'] < 3.14

#piRSquared's data sample
df = df[np.logical_and.reduce([m1, m2, m3, m4])]
print (df)
           column A  column B
2018-01-04     Done  2.533385
2018-01-06     Done  2.789072
2018-01-08     Done  2.230017
```

Answer (score 7):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((200,3)))
df['date'] = pd.date_range('2018-1-1', periods=200, freq='D')
df = df.set_index(['date'])
print(df.loc['2018-2-1':'2018-2-10'])
```

Hope! it will helpful

Comment: That shows how to filter by date, but not how to filter by other columns at the same time. What if I want to filter by rows within a date range and the values in column A are less than 3.14? I could do:
df[(df.index > datetime(2018,1,1)) & (df.index < datetime(2018,1,10)) & (df['column A'] < 3.14)]
but that seems a little cumbersome.

Answer (score -1):

I did this below to filter for both dataframes to have the same date

```
corn_url = 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?bgcolor=%23e1e9f0&chart_type=line&drp=0&fo=open%20sans&graph_bgcolor=%23ffffff&height=450&mode=fred&recession_bars=on&txtcolor=%23444444&ts=12&tts=12&width=1168&nt=0&thu=0&trc=0&show_legend=yes&show_axis_titles=yes&show_tooltip=yes&id=WPU012202&scale=left&cosd=1971-01-01&coed=2020-04-01&line_color=%234572a7&link_values=false&line_style=solid&mark_type=none&mw=3&lw=2&ost=-99999&oet=99999&mma=0&fml=a&fq=Monthly&fam=avg&fgst=lin&fgsnd=2009-06-01&line_index=1&transformation=lin&vintage_date=2020-06-09&revision_date=2020-06-09&nd=1971-01-01'
wheat_url ='https://fred.stlouisfed.org/graph/fredgraph.csv?bgcolor=%23e1e9f0&chart_type=line&drp=0&fo=open%20sans&graph_bgcolor=%23ffffff&height=450&mode=fred&recession_bars=on&txtcolor=%23444444&ts=12&tts=12&width=1168&nt=0&thu=0&trc=0&show_legend=yes&show_axis_titles=yes&show_tooltip=yes&id=WPU0121&scale=left&cosd=1947-01-01&coed=2020-04-01&line_color=%234572a7&link_values=false&line_style=solid&mark_type=none&mw=3&lw=2&ost=-99999&oet=99999&mma=0&fml=a&fq=Monthly&fam=avg&fgst=lin&fgsnd=2009-06-01&line_index=1&transformation=lin&vintage_date=2020-06-09&revision_date=2020-06-09&nd=1947-01-01'


corn = pd.read_csv(corn_url,index_col=0,parse_dates=True)
wheat = pd.read_csv(wheat_url,index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

    corn.head()
    PP Index 1982
    DATE    
    1971-01-01  63.4
    1971-02-01  63.6
    1971-03-01  62.0
    1971-04-01  60.8
    1971-05-01  60.2

wheat.head()
PP Index 1982
DATE    
1947-01-01  53.1
1947-02-01  56.5
1947-03-01  68.0
1947-04-01  66.0
1947-05-01  66.7


wheat = wheat[wheat.index > '1970-12-31']

wheat.head()
PP Index 1982
DATE    
1971-01-01  42.6
1971-02-01  42.6
1971-03-01  41.4
1971-04-01  41.7
1971-05-01  41.8
```

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the OP's question, which is how to *simultaneously filter on date and non-date criteria*; this only filters on date, which the OP already did in the question.

Comment: @fantabolous it's better to downvote, and then vote to delete, as this is technically an answer, even if it's a wrong answer.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney thanks. I had already downvoted; don't think I can vote to delete unless it has a negative score?