# Row-wise mapping of list of DataFrames in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operators

I have a list of data frames in Python (3) with boolean values and I want the row-wise AND of the list, but I have no idea how to do it:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({'v' : [True, True, True, True]})
d2 = pd.DataFrame({'v' : [False, True, True, True]})
d3 = pd.DataFrame({'v' : [False, True, False, True]})

dfs = [d1, d2, d3]
```

What I'd like to have is a data frame with the values [False, True, False, True]. I've tried using a lambda with `apply` but I have no idea if that's possible with a list of values of which I do not know the size. And I did not see a `foldLeft` (or similar option) to apply a binary operator on a list of values or DataFrame columns.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check if all `True`s per rows:

```
print (pd.concat(dfs, axis=1))
      v      v      v
0  True  False  False
1  True   True   True
2  True   True  False
3  True   True   True

print (pd.concat(dfs, axis=1).all(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Or [`np.logical_and.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20528328) with list comprehension:

```
print (np.logical_and.reduce([x['v'] for x in dfs]))
[False  True False  True]
```