# Dynamic data selection using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

i have a dynamic situation, wherein i want to filter the data as per bellow logic.

```
dynamic_cols = ['A', 'B'. ...]
dynamic_values = [1,2,...]

data_frame.LOC[data_frame[dynamic_cols == dynamic_values ]]
```

i have used pandas, and numpy.

Any suggestion on this please?

Ex: In above case i want to filter the rows where in `A=1 and Column B=2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [np.logical_and + reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2901002) of all masks created by `list comprehension` or create helper `DataFrame` and [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':[1,2,4,1,5,4],
         'B':[2,8,9,2,2,3],
         'C':[3,3,5,3,1,0],

})

print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  2  8  3
2  4  9  5
3  1  2  3
4  5  2  1
5  4  3  0
```

---

```
dynamic_cols = ['A','B','C']
dynamic_values = [1, 2, 3]

m = np.logical_and.reduce([df[a] == b for a, b in (zip(dynamic_cols, dynamic_values))])
df1 = df[m]
print (df1)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
3  1  2  3
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([dynamic_values], columns=dynamic_cols)
df1 = df.merge(df2)
print (df1)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
3  1  2  3
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. It worked for me. But one more question..`pd.DataFrame([dynamic_values], columns=dynamic_cols)` if i want to update the column `D` in the main `df` how can i do it now

Comment: @Geek - Not sure if understand, because I dont know how looks data, is possible specify it more? E.g create data sample? Be free use a nd modify sample data from my answer.

Comment: your data example is correct. Its just based on multiple column values i need to update a column in df

Comment: @Geek - hmm, then is better first solution, `df.loc[m, 'D'] = 10`

Comment: yes this is the exact solution. When i know `m`. i.e if `m` is like `a=1`. But my case is dynamic, means in one scenario `m` is `a=1` in another `[a,b]=[1,1]`

Comment: So `m = np.logical_and.reduce([df[a] == b for a, b in (zip(dynamic_cols, dynamic_values))])` is not possible use?