# Pandas- using "any" and "all" on multipls series outside of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I am looking for an equivalent to df.any() and df.all() that would work on series that are not in a dataframe.
I would rather not use the | and & operators, because i want to chain the result with other methods in a more readable way.

For example, I have two series of booleans of same length- s1, s2.
I would like to be able to do something like this:

pd.any(s1, s2)

That would return the same result as this:

s1 | s2

I also found a way to do do "and" comparison:

s1.add(s2)

The above statements returns the same result as:

s1 & s2

It seems to me like there might be a more explicit way to do an "and" operation.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) or [`numpy.logical_or`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html):

```
np.logical_and(s1, s2)
```

Or:

```
np.logical_or(s1, s2)
```

If there is multiple `Series` add [`reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2901002):

```
np.logical_and.reduce([s1, s2, s3])
```

Last if need new `Series` use constructor:

```
pd.Series(np.logical_and(s1, s2), index=s1.index)
```

**Notice:**

*Those methods ignore the series index, so the series must be sorted before passing them to the method for same indices in both.*

Comment: Thanks. I tested it and it works as I wanted! I would just like to note that according to my tests those methods ignore the series index, so the series must be sorted before passing them to the method