# Create New Column with Multiple Matches

Tags: python, pandas

**Sample DF:**

I have a df with columns like `Zone` , `New_Zone`, `Country`, `New_Region` & `Currency`

`Currency` column has values like `EUR`, `AUD`, `BLR`,`RUB`

`Zone` columns has values like `EU`, `Africa`, `NAZ`

`New_Zone` has values like `EU`, `Europe`, `EUROPE`, `Africa`, `NAZ`, `AFRICA`

`Country` has values like `Australia`, `Brazil`, `Russia`, `Ukraine`, `USA`

`New_Region` has values like `Australia`, `Brazil`, `USA`

So, columns `Zone` and `New_Zone` contains almost similar values and `New_Region` and `Country` almost similar values

**Ask:**

I want to make a new column called `Currency_Match` with below conditions:

1. If Zone is EU **OR**(logical) New_Zone is EU, Europe or EUROPE **AND**(logical)Currency is `EUR` then Yes else No
2. If Country is Australia **OR**(logical) New_Region is Austraila **AND**(logical) Currency is `AUD` then Yes else No
3. If Country is Brazil**OR**(logical) New_Region is Brazil **AND**(logical) Currency is `BLR` then Yes else No
4. If Country is Korea**OR**(logical) New_Region is korea**AND**(logical) Currency is `KRW` then Yes else No
5. If Zone is Africa **OR**(logical) New_Zone is Africa or AFRICA, **AND**(logical)Currency is `NGN` then Yes else No

6 If Zone is NAZ **OR**(logical) New_Zone is NAZ, **AND**(logical)Currency is `USD` then Yes else No

7 If Country is Russia , Ukraine **OR**(logical) New_Region is Russia**AND**(logical) Currency is `RUB` then Yes else No

I have overall 7 conditions like these above ones

**Code:**

```
        df['Currency_Match']=df.apply(lambda row: "Yes" if (((row['Zone'] == "EU")|(row['New_Zone'] =='Europe')|(row['New_Zone'] =='EU')|(row['New_Zone'] =='EUROPE')) 
& (row["Contract - Original Currency Code"] == "EUR"))
     else 'No',axis=1)
```

**Problem:**

Above code works well but when I write the other conditions like this it updates the column again and again.

Is their any other approach I can do this and also less cumbersome than this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create each conditions for separate rows for readable code, chain by `|` or `&` for bitwise `OR` or `AND` to final mask and pass to [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m1 = (df['Zone'] == "EU")|(df['New_Zone'].isin(['Europe','EUROPE','EU'])
m2 = (df["Contract - Original Currency Code"] == "EUR")

m3 = (df['Region'] == "Australia")|(df['New_Region'] =='Australia')
m4 = (df["Contract - Original Currency Code"] == "AUD")

m5 = (df['Region'] == "Brazil")|(df['New_Region'] =='Brazil')
m6 = (df["Contract - Original Currency Code"] == "BLR")

mask = (m1 & m2) | (m3 & m4) | (m5 & m6)

df['Currency_Match'] = np.where(mask, "Yes", 'No')
```

EDIT: for dynamic solution create dictionary by currency with list of zones and regions and pass to [`logical_or.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2901002) in `dict comprehension`:

```
#zone dict
d1 = {'EUR':['Europe','EUROPE','EU'],'NGN':['Africa','AFRICA'],'USD':['NAZ']}

#region dict
d2 = {'AUD':['Australia'], 'BLR':['Brazil'],'KRW':['Korea'],'RUB':['Russia','Ukraine']}

m1 = [(df['Zone'].isin(v) | df['New_Zone'].isin(v)) & 
      (df["Contract - Original Currency Code"] == k) 
       for k, v in d1.items()]
print (m1)

m2 = [(df['Region'].isin(v) | df['New_Region'].isin(v)) & 
      (df["Contract - Original Currency Code"] == k) 
       for k, v in d2.items()]
print (m2)

mask = np.logical_or.reduce(m1) | np.logical_or.reduce(m2)

df['Currency_Match'] = np.where(mask, "Yes", 'No')
```

Comment: Ok..this for me will have m1 .... m14. Is there no shorter way in terms of lines of code to accomplish this?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - hmmm, give me some time

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - there is only one condition for `Zone` and all 14 are for `Regions` ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - Is possible add some sample data 3, 4 rows? For verify solution.

Comment: OK, I add solution and if problem, you can add data, OK?

Comment: @jezrael what does `reduce()` do here??

Comment: @anky_91 - check link, there is it explained nice.

Comment: @jezrael:Edited the question and added all 7 conditons

Comment: @jezrael: Isn't m2 should be `for k, v in d2.items()` ?