# Numpy logical conditions for labeling the data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, where-clause

I am trying to create another label column which is based on multiple conditions in my existing data

```
df

ind group people value value_50 val_minmax
 1     1    5    100    1        10
 1     2    2    90     1        na
 2     1    10   80     1        80
 2     2    20   40     0        na
 3     1    7    10     0        10
 3     2    23   30     0        na

import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

Then trying to put label on rows as per below conditions

```
df['label'] = np.where(np.logical_and(df.group == 2, df.value_50 == 1, df.value > 50), 1, 0)
```

but it is giving me an error

```
TypeError: return arrays must be of ArrayType
```

How to perform it in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&` between masks:

```
df['label'] = np.where((df.group == 2) & (df.value_50 == 1) & (df.value > 50), 1, 0)
```

Alternative:

```
df['label'] = ((df.group == 2) & (df.value_50 == 1) & (df.value > 50)).astype(int)
```

Your solution should working if use [`reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566) with list of boolean masks:

```
mask = np.logical_and.reduce([df.group == 2, df.value_50 == 1, df.value > 50])
df['label'] = np.where(mask, 1, 0)
#alternative
#df['label'] = mask.astype(int)
```