# Python Pandas multiple search terms

Tags: python, pandas, search

Using: Python 3.7.3, Pandas 0.24.2

I am in the process of writing some search functionality in Python using Pandas data frames.

I have a line of code that search for results containing all keywords in a list:

```
processed = df.loc[(df.Keywords.str.contains("magnetic")) & (df.Keywords.str.contains("board")) & (df.Keywords.str.contains("white"))]
```

I need to make the search terms dynamic i.e. generate an equivalent to this line based on a variable with any number of words in it.

I have managed to code this in regex however it is significantly slower than using the method above.  I can pass one search term in simply enough, but not a variable number of terms.

I also have to consider the fact that search terms may be partial, i.e. search term of "agnet" should return if row contains "magnet" etc.

Any options gratefully received.

To clarify:

I've already tried using options like :

```
processed = df[df['Keywords'].str.contains('|'.join(search_list))]
```

Unfortunately this returns any row that contains any of the search terms.  i.e Magnetic `OR` Board `OR` White.  What I need would be to return a row that contains Magnetic `AND` Board `AND` White.  Image searching for products on Amazon, that would be the closest comparison.

Results from suggestions below:

I have tested the options provided below with the following code:

search_terms = "magnetic Board White"
    search_terms = search_terms.lower()
    search_list = search_terms.split()

```
start_time = time.time()
processed = df.loc[(df.Keywords.str.contains("magnetic")) & (df.Keywords.str.contains("board")) & (df.Keywords.str.contains("white"))]
print("--- Original %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
mask = pd.concat([df['Keywords'].str.contains(x) for x in search_list], axis=1).all(axis=1)
processed = df[mask]
print("--- Concat %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
processed = df[np.logical_and.reduce([df['Keywords'].str.contains(x) for x in search_list])]
print("--- Numpy reduce %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

On the data set I am using I had the following results:

```
--- Original 0.09292888641357422 seconds ---
--- Concat 0.09293532371520996 seconds ---
--- Numpy reduce 0.11991643905639648 seconds ---
```

As such I have chosen to use the Concat DataFrame.all method suggest by @jezrael.

Many thanks for the support all.

Comment: Build a function which takes a dataframe,column and a list as input. Then use the method from the linked answer to return you the rows you want. Something like: `def search_string(dataframe, col, words)`. Then as body `return dataframe[dataframe[col].str.contains('|'.join(words))]`

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question. OP is searching for results which contain **all** search terms, the linked question searched for **any** search term.

Comment: You are right @thesilkworm, voted for reopen

Comment: @Matthew, could you add some example data so we can reproduce an answer for you.

Comment: Many thanks @Erfan.  Is there any way I can get the duplicate flag removed?  Or is it just a case of I have to get multiple people to vote re-open?

Comment: reopened question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.logical_and.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528328/numpy-logical-or-for-more-than-two-arguments) for all mask in list comprehension and then filter:

```
processed = df[np.logical_and.reduce([df['Keywords'].str.contains(x) for x in search_list])]
```

Another solution with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
mask = pd.concat([df['Keywords'].str.contains(x) for x in search_list], axis=1).all(axis=1)
processed = df[mask]
```

Comment: Many thanks, I'll test for speed on my data set and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Both of these options worked, I found that the concat dataframe.all method was the quickest with the data sets I tested.  Many thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

try this inserting all string in list and use str.contains with join

```
list_str=['board', 'white', 'magnetic']
df = df[df['Keyword'].str.contains('|'.join(list_str))]
```

If you want closest match

```
results= df[np.logical_and.reduce([df['Keywords'].str.contains(x) for x in list_str])]
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this essentially builds a regex, and takes advantage of `contains` knowing how to handle regexes.

Comment: Thanks for the option.  Please see my added clarification above - I'm looking for ALL terms not one in a list.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using `numpy.logical_and` and `reduce`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Keywords': ['whiteboard', 'white', 'board', 'magnetic whiteboard', 'magnet']})
search = ['white', 'board', 'magnet']

df[np.logical_and.reduce([(df.Keywords.str.contains(s)) for s in search])]
```

Results:

```
              Keywords
3  magnetic whiteboard
```

I haven't tested the speed but I think it'll perform well compared to regex solutions.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll test for speed on my data set and let you know the outcome.

Comment: Great answer.  I did find that the concat method listed by @jezrael was quicker however so I have accepted that as the answer but have upvoted this as working perfectly. Thanks for the help.