# How to apply multiple masks to a dataframe at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas

I have set up three masks for my `df`, and I want to filter out these values.

For example, some random masks:

```
mask1 = df['column1'].isnull()
mask2 = df['column2'] > 5
mask3 = df['column3'].str.contains('hello')
```

Now how do I combine these masks to filter **out** these values? 
Is this the correct way? Using both `~` and `|` ?

```
masked_df = df[~mask1 | ~mask2 | ~mask3]
```

I have so many rows in my dataframe that I can't be 100% sure with manual checking to see if it's correct.

Comment: Looks fine to me. But why not flip the conditions as `df['column1'].notnull()` and `mask2 = df['column2'] < 5`?

Comment: Because my brain doesn't work that way :). I want to create masks like `mask1 = I do not want this.` and `mask2 = I do not want that` etc.

Comment: It dependes if you want to filter out lines who fill all the conditions, and then you are right, or you want to filter out lines who fill any of the conditions, and in that case you should use `&` instead of `|`

Answer (score 12):

Your solution is nice, but also is posible use bitwise `AND` and invert chained conditions:

```
masked_df = df[~(mask1 & mask2 & mask3)]
```

If masks are in list, solution above is rewritten with [`np.logical_and.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528328/numpy-logical-or-for-more-than-two-arguments/20528566#20528566):

```
masks = [mask1, mask2, mask3]

m = df[~np.logical_and.reduce(masks)]
print (m)
   A  column1  column2 column3
2  c      4.0        9   hello
3  d      5.0        4   hello
4  e      5.0        2   hello
5  f      4.0        3   hello
```

Comment: Really nice add-on with the `np.logical_and.reduce()`, this is how I used that in my case where I had a dict containing the masks:

`df[~np.logical_and.reduce([a for a in dict.values()])]`