# Dataframe column filter from a list of tuples

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, filter, tuples

I'm trying to create a function to filter a dataframe from a list of tuples. I've created the below function but it doesn't seem to be working.
The list of tuples would be have dataframe column name, and a min value and a max value to filter.

eg:

```
eg_tuple = [('colname1', 10, 20), ('colname2', 30, 40), ('colname3', 50, 60)]
```

My attempted function is below:

```
def col_cut(df, cutoffs):
    for c in cutoffs:
        df_filter = df[ (df[c[0]] >= c[1]) & (df[c[0]] <= c[2])]
    return df_filter
```

Note that the function should not filter on rows where the value is equal to max or min. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you each time take `df` as the source to filter. You should filter with:

```
def col_cut(df, cutoffs):
    df_filter = df
    for col, mn, mx in cutoffs:
        dfcol = df_filter[col]
        df_filter = df_filter[(dfcol >= mn) & (dfcol <= mx)]
    return df_filter
```

Note that you can use [**`.between(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) here:

```
def col_cut(df, cutoffs):
    df_filter = df
    for col, mn, mx in cutoffs:
        df_filter = df_filter[df_filter[col].between(mn, mx)]
    return df_filter
```

Comment: Thank you very much Willem. That worked exactly as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Use [np.logical_and + reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2901002) of all masks created by `list comprehension` with [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
def col_cut(df, cutoffs):
    mask = np.logical_and.reduce([df[col].between(min1,max1) for col,min1,max1 in cutoffs])
    return df[mask]
```