# Filter rows from multiple date columns based on the specific year and month in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

For the given dataframe as follows:

```
   id  start_date    end_date
0   1   2014/5/26   2014/5/27
1   2   2014/6/27   2014/6/28
2   3   2014/7/20   2014/7/21
3   4   2014/9/12   2014/9/13
4   5  2014/10/10  2014/10/11
5   6   2020/3/20   2020/4/21
6   7   2020/4/10   2020/4/11
7   8   2020/4/15   2020/4/16
8   9   2020/3/23   2020/3/24
9  10    2020/4/6    2020/4/7
```

I want to filter rows which either `start_date` or `end_date` is in the range of `2020-02, 2020-03, 2020-04`, thanks for sharing other optional solutions besides mine.

The lookforwarding result will like this:

```
   id start_date   end_date
5   6 2020-03-20 2020-04-21
6   7 2020-04-10 2020-04-11
7   8 2020-04-15 2020-04-16
9  10 2020-04-06 2020-04-07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is better [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for processing by columns, [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) is for processing elementwise:

```
df[['start_date', 'end_date']] = (df[['start_date', 'end_date']]
                                   .apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format = '%Y/%m/%d')))
```

Then for filtering is used months periods by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
df = (df[(df['start_date'].dt.to_period('m')== '2020-04') | 
         (df['end_date'].dt.to_period('m')== '2020-04')])
print (df)
   id start_date   end_date
5   6 2020-03-20 2020-04-21
6   7 2020-04-10 2020-04-11
7   8 2020-04-15 2020-04-16
9  10 2020-04-06 2020-04-07
```

Solution with loop by columns is possible by [`np.logical_or.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2901002), solution is better if more columns:

```
c = ['start_date', 'end_date']
df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format = '%Y/%m/%d'))

df = df[np.logical_or.reduce([df[x].dt.to_period('m')== '2020-04' for x in c])]
print (df)
   id start_date   end_date
5   6 2020-03-20 2020-04-21
6   7 2020-04-10 2020-04-11
7   8 2020-04-15 2020-04-16
9  10 2020-04-06 2020-04-07
```

Comment: Thank you, if I need to filter by multiple months, for example `2020-02, 2020-03, 2020-04`? My solutions will need to add too much code I think.

Comment: @ahbon - I think `isin` should be used here, try `L = [pd.Period('2020-03'), pd.Period('2020-05')]

df = (df[(df['start_date'].dt.to_period('m').isin(L)) | 
         (df['end_date'].dt.to_period('m').isin(L))])`

Comment: I use `L = [pd.Period('2019-10'), pd.Period('2019-11'), pd.Period('2019-12')]` to filter `2019 Q4` data, but August data is inside, any ideas?

Comment: @ahbon - I test too and also cannot find problem, but last I got it - also match years?

Comment: Just test with `df[np.logical_or.reduce([df[x].dt.to_period('m').isin(L) for x in c])]`, get same result as `df[(df['start_date'].dt.to_period('m').isin(L)) | (df['end_date'].dt.to_period('m').isin(L))]`.

Comment: @ahbon - I got you, `isin` is like `or`, but you want `and`. Give me some time

Comment: @ahbon - Do you need general solution or filtering by quarter?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, with your solution in comment I get correct answer.

Comment: @ahbon - But if want `and` then is possible use `df = df[np.logical_and.reduce([(df['start_date'].dt.to_period('m').eq(x)) | (df['end_date'].dt.to_period('m').eq(x)) for x in L])]`

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works:

```
df[['start_date', 'end_date']] = df[['start_date', 'end_date']].applymap(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format = '%Y/%m/%d'))
df.loc[((df['start_date'].dt.year == 2020) & (df['start_date'].dt.month==4)) | ((df['end_date'].dt.year == 2020) & (df['end_date'].dt.month==4))]
```

Out:

```
   id start_date   end_date
5   6 2020-03-20 2020-04-21
6   7 2020-04-10 2020-04-11
7   8 2020-04-15 2020-04-16
9  10 2020-04-06 2020-04-07
```