# Groupby and keep only groups that contain values within a list

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

hello I have a df such as

```
list_vales_regex=['ABC',DEF']
Groups Names
G1 ABC_9
G1 ZTY_2
G1 SGG56
G1 BBCHU
G1 DEFE_8
G2 ABC_6
G2 GGDY
G3 ABC_6
G3 DEF98
G3 DEF89
G4 DEF_09
G4 DGE7
G5 DGGE22
G5 DGGE23
```

and I would like to keep only groups that do contain both (`ABC` and `DEF` Names)

Here in the exemple only `G1` and `G3` have ot be kept. 
Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get values by list to helper `Series` by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `|` for join values for regex `or` and then compare values converted to `set`s per groups in [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
list_vales_regex=['ABC','DEF']

s = df['Names'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(list_vales_regex)})', expand=False)
df = df[s.groupby(df['Groups']).transform(lambda x: set(x) >= set(list_vales_regex))]
print (df)
  Groups   Names
0     G1   ABC_9
1     G1   ZTY_2
2     G1   SGG56
3     G1   BBCHU
4     G1  DEFE_8
7     G3   ABC_6
8     G3   DEF98
9     G3   DEF89
```

Or filter by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) (if not large data, because slowier):

```
df = df[s.groupby(df['Groups']).transform('nunique').ge(2)]
```

Another approach is find `groups` with matched all values of list in list comprehension with [np.logical_and.reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20528328/2901002) for test if match at least one value by [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html), then filter groups by first value of list by `L[0]` and pass to [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
list_vales_regex=['ABC','DEF']

L = [df.set_index('Groups')['Names'].str.contains(x).any(level=0) for x in list_vales_regex]

df = df[df['Groups'].isin(L[0].index[np.logical_and.reduce(L)])]
print (df)
  Groups   Names
0     G1   ABC_9
1     G1   ZTY_2
2     G1   SGG56
3     G1   BBCHU
4     G1  DEFE_8
7     G3   ABC_6
8     G3   DEF98
9     G3   DEF89
```

**Details**:

```
print (np.logical_and.reduce(L))
[ True False  True False False]

print (L[0].index[np.logical_and.reduce(L)])
Index(['G1', 'G3'], dtype='object', name='Groups')
```

Comment: We could do : `df.loc[s.groupby(df['Groups']).transform('nunique').ge(2)]`

Comment: @ansev - Super, or similar `df = df[s.groupby(df['Groups']).transform('nunique').ge(2)]`