# Pandas - Create multiple filters and apply to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have created multiple filters for a Dataframe:

```
filt1 = ~df["message"].str.contains("<Media omitted>", na=False),
filt2 = ~df["message"].str.contains("http://", na=False),
filt3 = ~df["message"].str.contains("Dropped pin", na=False),
```

I can filter the dataframe using:

```
df[filt1 & filt2 & filt3]
```

But as I add more filters this seems like a stupid way to filter.
How do I apply multiple filters to a dataframe?

I tried adding each filter to a list doing `df[filterlist]` and `df[*filterlist]` but these do not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [np.logical_and.reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20528328/2901002):

```
filterlist = [filt1, filt2, filt3]

df[np.logical_and.reduce(filterlist)]
```

Or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test all `True`s per rows:

```
df[pd.concat(filterlist, axis=1).all(axis=1)]
```

If possible use `|` for regex `or`:

```
filt = ~df["message"].str.contains("<Media omitted>|http://|Dropped pin", na=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` to merge list for regex

```
df[~df.message.str.contains('|'.join(filterlist))]
```