# How to properly set python kwargs as conditions without nested if-else? (python, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a DataFrame looks like the following,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['', 'Dave', 'Tom'],
    'Age':[20, 30, None],
    'Job':['singer', 'teacher', 'student'],
})
```

and I'd like to make a function that can help me filter the value I want for analysis

```
def filt(name=False, age=False, job=False) -> pd.DataFrame:
    '''
    this function return the dataframe with selected param
    '''
    if name:
        df = df[df.Name.notna()]
    if age:
        df = df[df.Age.notna()]
    if job:
        df = df[df.Job.notna()]

    return df


# Expected Usage: return the dataframe where "Name" and "Age" should not be empty.
filt(df, name=True, age=True)
```

In real world I would like to have at least 10 kwargs from case to case, and this code seems to be redundant. What is the convention to set param without using too many if-else statements?

---

EDIT:
sorry for misunderstood with filtering na values only. There's also cases like " filter job=='students' ", and the default param would be all of them.

```
# i.e. How could the function possible looks like

def filt(df, name=False, job=False, age=False, 
         selected_name=None, selected_job=None):

    # make the default selected_name value to all of them
    selected_name = tuple(df.Name.tolist()) if not selected_name else tuple(selected_name) #tuple() cause dict keys cannot be list
    selected_job = tuple(df.Job.tolist()) if not selected_job else tuple(selected_job) #tuple() cause dict keys cannot be list
    
    # Try to make dict when keys=True, use the values as conditions
    filtlist = {
      name: df.Name!='',
      age : df.Age!='',
      job : df.Job!='',
      selected_name: df.Name.isin(selected_name),
      selected_job: df.Job.isin(selected_job)
    }


    x = [filtlist[i] for i in filtlist.keys() if i]
    # since I pass in 3 kwargs, len(x)=3, i have 3 conditions. 
    # ^ I stuck here, How do I know concat those conditions together without knowing how many conditions I have?
    # '&'.join(x) returns a string, I cannot do this
    
    return df[x[0] & x[1] & x[2]] # I manually do this cause I know I have 3 kwargs. just to make sample run.

filt(df,name=True, age=True, selected_job=['teacher']) #yeah...for some reason name=True does not seems to work...`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with possible pass list of columns names for remove missing values, because here are empty strings I replace them to missing values:

```
def filt(df, cols) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return df.dropna(subset=cols)

df = filt(df.replace('', np.nan), ['Name', 'Age'])
print (df)
   Name   Age      Job
1  Dave  30.0  teacher
```

If need pass only one column name:

```
def filt(df, col) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return df.dropna(subset=[col])


df = filt(df.replace('', np.nan), 'Name')
print (df)
   Name   Age      Job
1  Dave  30.0  teacher
2   Tom   NaN  student
```

Another idea if need pass atributes use `**attrs` parameter and then procssing dictionary - e.g. here use `title` for match columns names:

```
def filt(df, **attrs) -> pd.DataFrame:
    #for testing
    #print (attrs)
    cols = [k.title() for k, v in attrs.items() if v]
    return df.dropna(subset=cols)

df = filt(df.replace('', np.nan), name=True, age=True)
print (df)
   Name   Age      Job
1  Dave  30.0  teacher
```

EDIT: In your solution use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63560043/pandas-create-multiple-filters-and-apply-to-dataframe/63560065#63560065):

```
return df[np.logical_and.reduce(x)]
```

Comment: The last idea is beautiful, and it could be easily modified to be a custom method. P.S. You might want to remove your testing `print(attrs)`

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question. The solution should be perfectly fine filtering NaN values, but what if I need to do other sorting ? Sorry for late update

Comment: @Cookie - Understand problem, give me some time, please.

Comment: @Cookie - answer was edited.