# How to slice DataFrame using logical("or") and for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am a very beginner of Python.

The goal is to slice the column of DataFrame('incen') which contains specific device codes...

But the device codes keep changed, so I made it into a list('device_code').

I tried to use for loop like this way:

```py
for a in device_code:
     incen[(incen.device_name.str.contains(a) == True)]
```

However, it couldn't be merged into one DataFrame.

So I solved it into this way which is super inefficient:

```py
incen[(incen.device_name.str.contains(device_code[0]) == True)]|incen[(incen.device_name.str.contains(device_code[1]) == True)]|incen[(incen.device_name.str.contains(device_code[2]) == True)]|incen[(incen.device_name.str.contains(device_code[3]) == True)]
...and so on...
```

Let me understand how to use logical 'or' and for loop at the same time. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lsit comprehension with [np.logical_or.reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2901002), compare by `True` is not necessary:

```
L = [incen.device_name.str.contains(a, na=False) for a in device_code]
incen[np.logical_or.reduce(L)]
```