# Formatting rows that satisfy conditions Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, formatting

I am trying to format the data in `input.csv` so that it returns the indexes that satisfies the conditions of `Indexes`. I want the code to print out all the indexes of rows that have all the values defined in the `#intervals`. Only the first row of element `[ 2.  2. 30.]` satisfies for the limits defined at the `Indexes` variables. Essentially I want to print out all the rows: Thats satisfy the condition: if `column['MxU'] >= MxU and column['SNPT'] >= SNPT..... and column['MxD'] >= MxD`

input.csv file:

```
element,LNPT,SNPT,NLP,NSP,TNT,TPnL,MxPnL,MnPnL,MxU,MxD
[ 2.  2. 30.],0,0,4,4,8,-0.1,-0.0,-0.1,17127,-3
[ 2.  2. 40.],0,0,2,2,4,0.0,-0.0,-0.0,17141,-3
[ 2.  2. 50.],0,0,2,2,4,0.0,-0.0,-0.0,17139,-3
[ 2.  2. 60.],2,0,6,6,12,0.5,2.3,-1.9,17015,-3
[ 2.  2. 70.],1,0,4,4,8,0.3,0.3,-0.0,17011,-3
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')

#intervals
MxU= 17100
SNPT= 1
NLP= 3
MnPnL= -0.1
MxD= 0

#variables used for formatting
Indexes = [MxU,SNPT,NLP,MnPnL,MxD]
#all columns in csv listed
columns = ['LNPT', 'SNPT', 'NLP', 'MxPnL', 'NSP', 'TNT', 'TPnL', 'MnPnL','MxU','MxD']

def intersect() :#function for 
    for i in columns:
        if str(Indexes[i]) in columns[i]:
            for k in Indexes:
                formating = df[columns] >= Indexes[k]
        
    
intersect() #calling function
```

Expected Output:

```
row: 1 element:[ 2.  2. 30.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your point, you can store your column interval in a dictionary. Then loop through the columns you want to check to compare with the interval dictionary.

You can use [`np.logical_and and reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2901002) to simplify the loop.

```py
import numpy as np

intervals = {
    'MxU': 17100,
    'SNPT': 1,
    'NLP': 3,
    'MnPnL': -0.1,
    'MxD': 0
}

columns = ['NLP', 'MnPnL']

mask = np.logical_and.reduce([df[col] >= intervals[col] for col in columns])
```

Then use boolean indexing to select the desired rows

```py
df_ = df.loc[mask, 'element']
```

```
# print(df_)

0    [ 2.  2. 30.]
4    [ 2.  2. 70.]
Name: element, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi I am trying to make the `columns` modular could you also take a look at this issue I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67131268/formatting-a-datasheet-with-given-limits-with-pandas-python

Comment: @tonyselcuk My bad, you could just post your question under this answer.

Comment: @tonyselcuk Edited.