# filter dataframe using dictionary with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a **dataframe** that is consist of 3 columns when user select what are the **columns** and **values** that he want to apply a filter on it the system create a **dictionary** with these **keys==columns name** : **values = cell values**, I want to display the filtered dataframe as a table.

**I want to compare between the dictionary and  dataframe  and display the filtered data.**

## code:

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.DataFrame({
            "source_number":[11199,11328,11287,32345,12342,1232,13456,123244,13456],
             "location":["loc2","loc1","loc3","loc1","loc2","loc2","loc3","loc2","loc1"],
             "category":["cat1","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat2"],
             })  

#let say the created dictionary have the below value
sidebars = {"location":["loc1","loc2"],"category":["cat1","cat3"]}
```

## excpected result :

```
source_number   location    category
 32345             loc1       cat3
 11199             loc2       cat1
 12342             loc2       cat3
 1232              loc2       cat3
 123244            loc2       cat3
```

## code with streamlit:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st 
    
    
df =pd.DataFrame({
            "source_number":                        [ 
             [11199,11328,11287,32345,12342,1232,13456,123244,13456],
             "location":          
             ["loc2","loc1","loc3","loc1","loc2","loc2","loc3","loc2","loc1"],
              "category": 
             ["cat1","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat2"],
             })  
    
    is_check = st.checkbox("Display Data")
    if is_check:
        st.table(df)
    
    
    columns = st.sidebar.multiselect("Enter the variables", df.columns)
    
    sidebars = {}
    for y in columns:
        ucolumns=list(df[y].unique())
    
        sidebars[y]=st.sidebar.multiselect('Filter '+y, ucolumns)   
    L = [df[k].isin(v) if isinstance(v, list) 
         else df[k].eq(v) 
         for k, v in sidebars.items() if k in df.columns]
    df = df[np.logical_and.reduce(L)]
    st.table(df)
```

How to get the excpected result i know that i need to iterate over the dictionary  and compare

After i solved the comapring between dictionary and dataframe based on the answer of **@jezrael**.

it still display the below error at the first :

```
KeyError: True
Traceback:
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 333, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "F:\AIenv\streamlit\app.py", line 326, in <module>
    df = df[np.logical_and.reduce(L)]
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dict comprehension for select dynamic by columns names with values in lists by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with  [`np.logical_and and reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2901002) trick:

*Notice - If use `isin` in dict all values has to be `list`*

```
df = df[np.logical_and.reduce([df[k].isin(v) for k, v in sidebars.items()])]
print (df)
   source_number location category
0          11199     loc2     cat1
3          32345     loc1     cat3
4          12342     loc2     cat3
5           1232     loc2     cat3
7         123244     loc2     cat3
```

If possible scalars or lists in dict is possible use `if-else` in list comprehension with test scalars by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
#let say the created dictionary have the below value
sidebars = {"location":["loc1","loc2"],"category":"cat3"}

L = [df[k].isin(v) if isinstance(v, list) else df[k].eq(v) for k, v in sidebars.items()]
df = df[np.logical_and.reduce(L)]
print (df)
   source_number location category
3          32345     loc1     cat3
4          12342     loc2     cat3
5           1232     loc2     cat3
7         123244     loc2     cat3
```

EDIT: If possible some column no match by keys of dict is possible filter it (but then not filtered by this not matched key):

```
L = [df[k].isin(v) for k, v in sidebars.items() if k in df.columns]
```

```
L = [df[k].isin(v) if isinstance(v, list) 
     else df[k].eq(v) 
     for k, v in sidebars.items() if k in df.columns]
```

---

```
df = df[np.logical_and.reduce(L)]
```

EDIT:

First time code in streamlit, so possible better solutions, here is problem if passed empty dictionary.

So possible check it by `if bool(sidebars)`:

```
is_check = st.checkbox("Display Data")
if is_check:
    st.table(df)


columns = st.sidebar.multiselect("Enter the variables", df.columns)

sidebars = {}
for y in columns:
    ucolumns=list(df[y].unique())
    print (ucolumns)

    sidebars[y]=st.sidebar.multiselect('Filter '+y, ucolumns)   

if bool(sidebars):
    L = [df[k].isin(v) if isinstance(v, list) 
         else df[k].eq(v) 
         for k, v in sidebars.items() if k in df.columns]
    
    df1 = df[np.logical_and.reduce(L)]
    st.table(df1)
```

Comment: i used your answer but it display the below error:
`KeyError: True
Traceback:
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 333, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "F:\AIenv\streamlit\app.py", line 323, in <module>
    df = df[np.logical_and.reduce(L)]
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err`

what it means?

Comment: @user5980666 - I think there is no some column from keys of dict in DataFrame.

Comment: @user5980666 - Like `sidebars = {"some col":["loc1","loc2"],"category":["cat1","cat3"]}`

Comment: @user5980666 - It is possible filter ouput this not matched columns, added to answer.

Comment: this solve partially my problem.. because  when i run the code it display at the first this error:
`KeyError: True
Traceback:
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 333, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "F:\AIenv\streamlit\app.py", line 326, in <module>
    df = df[np.logical_and.reduce(L)]
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
File "f:\aienv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2893, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err`

Comment: i will edit my question and add some more details about my code

Comment: @user5980666 - What is error after `raise KeyError(key) from err` ?

Comment: there is nothing after the line `raise KeyError(key) from err`

Comment: @user5980666 - hmm, it seems error because empty dict is passed, because no default select

Comment: @user5980666 - If check yout cmd there is first passed `{}`

Comment: @user5980666 - Aded solution to answer.

Comment: yes that was the problem thank you.
can i relate the dropdownlists in my code to display just the values that are related to the first dropdownlist or the second ?
means if **category** have **cat1**  and **cat1** have **loc1**  and **loc2** without **loc3** i do not want to display **loc3** as an option.

Comment: @user5980666 - I can add some solution, but still I think better post new question, because not sure if exist something better

Comment: ok i will post new question hope that you will contribute and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and boolean indexing.

```py
df_ = df[df['location'].isin(sidebars['location']) & df['category'].isin(sidebars['category'])]
```

```
# print(df_)

   source_number location category
0          11199     loc2     cat1
3          32345     loc1     cat3
4          12342     loc2     cat3
5           1232     loc2     cat3
7         123244     loc2     cat3
```

If you want to filter by user chosen column, you can use

```py
from functools import reduce

user_choosen = ['location']

mask = reduce(lambda x, y: x & y, [df[col].isin(sidebars[col]) for col in user_choosen])

df_ = df[mask]
```

Comment: what if want to make the **df["location"]** dynamic ??
means that the user choose what will be the column name  can i make it based on the index of the column?? or is there another way to make the filter dynamic?

Comment: @user5980666 If user chooses what will be the column name, then assign user chosen to a variable, say `col`. You can use `df[col]`.

Comment: so maybe the user choose one columns not 2 and 1 or 2 values or 3 values ??
how this can be applied on my filter