# how to create dependent dropdownlist in python and streamlit?

Tags: python, pandas, drop-down-menu, multi-select

based on the answer  [of this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67119428/filter-dataframe-using-dictionary-with-multiple-values/67119491?noredirect=1#comment118641433_67119491) i was able to display the dataframe after apply the required filter.

I have  a streamlit code that display multiple dropdown lists

1. first dropdownlist has as option the columns name (its multiselection option)
2. the other dropdownlists will includes the unique values of the
   selected columns

[image]

what i want is that if the user choose the **cat3** and the **cat3** does not have a **loc2**
i want in the third dropdownlist to display just the **loc1** and **loc3** based on the records of the dataframe.

## code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st 

df =pd.DataFrame({
            "source_number":
             [11199,11328,11287,32345,12342,1232,13456,123244,13456],
             "location":          
             ["loc2","loc1","loc3","loc1","loc2","loc2","loc3","loc2","loc1"],
              "category": 
             ["cat1","cat2","cat1","cat3","cat3","cat3","cat2","cat3","cat2"],
             })  

is_check = st.checkbox("Display Data")
if is_check:
    st.table(df)


columns = st.sidebar.multiselect("Enter the variables", df.columns)

sidebars = {}
for y in columns:
    ucolumns=list(df[y].unique())
    print (ucolumns)

    sidebars[y]=st.sidebar.multiselect('Filter '+y, ucolumns)   

if bool(sidebars):
    L = [df[k].isin(v) if isinstance(v, list) 
         else df[k].eq(v) 
         for k, v in sidebars.items() if k in df.columns]
    
    df1 = df[np.logical_and.reduce(L)]
    st.table(df1)
```

Comment: hmmm, it is more complicated like I think, not sure if possible.

Comment: can't i check  if  let say what **cat2** has  as values in **location column** ??

Comment: If filter category is multi-choice, I don't think you can do it. If it's single choice, then you would filter the df and get all rows where column category==@category_choice and then pass that as options for the location filter.

Comment: yes i know if it was single selection but i was wondering if it can be applied on multiselection

Comment: maybe as a workaround could a button be clicked to populate the dropdowns after the multi choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another workaround could be filtering dataframe before populating each column values and using multiselect's default property in each multiselect instance. Not certain of performance though!

Something like below

```
with st.sidebar: #1st filter                                     
    FirstFilter = st.mulitiselect(default=df["FirstColumn"].unique())   

df2 = df.query("FirstColumn == @FirstFilter")

with st.sidebar: #2nd filter                                  
    SecondFilter = st.multiselect(deafult=df2["SecondCoulmn"].unique()

df3 = df2.query("SecondColumn == @SecondFilter")

with st.sidebar: #3rd filter*                                       
    ThirdFilter = st.multiselect(default=df3["ThirdColumn"].unique()
```