# Pandas: Find data frame string entries that contain a specific word more than once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**The Situation:**

I have a pandas DataFrame and would like to find all the entries of a certain columnn with a string that contains a specific word more than once and create a separate dataframe with from said results.

**What have I done?**

So far I have managed to get it to collect all the entries that contain the specified word at least once.

**The Code**:

```
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': ['2020', '2021', '2021'],
                       'Title': ['Energy calculation', 'Energy calculation with energy', 'Other calculation'])
    terms = ['energy']
    list_df = selection_df[selection_df['title'].str.contains('|'.join(terms), na=False, case=False)]
```

**The output:**

> ```
> 0 2020 Energy calculation
> 1 2021 Energy calculation with energy
> ```

**Then question**

I would like help in collecting only the second entry:

> ```
> 1 2021 Energy calculation with energy
> ```

Which contains the word energy more than once. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need test each value of list separately in [`Series.str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) for list of masks and then use [`np.logical_or.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528328/numpy-logical-or-for-more-than-two-arguments/20528566#20528566):

```
import re

terms = ['energy']
masks = [selection_df['Title'].str.count(re.escape(x), flags=re.I).gt(1) for x in terms]
list_df = selection_df[np.logical_or.reduce(masks)]
print (list_df)
 Year                           Title
1  2021  Energy calculation with energy
```

Alternative solution:

```
terms = ['energy']
masks = [selection_df['Title'].str.count(re.escape(x), flags=re.I).gt(1) for x in terms]
list_df = selection_df[pd.concat(masks, axis=1).any(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex with a capturing group and a reference:

```
import re
reg = r'.*(%s).*\1' % '|'.join(terms)
# line above constructs reg = '.*(energy|other|terms).*\\1'

selection_df[selection_df['Title'].str.match(reg, flags=re.I)]
```

output:

```
   Year                           Title
1  2021  Energy calculation with energy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas-series-str-extractall) with `collections.Counter`:

```py
import re
from collections import Counter

terms = ["energy", "calculation"]

x = (
    df["Title"]
    .str.extractall("(" + "|".join(map(re.escape, terms)) + ")", flags=re.I)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg(lambda x: Counter(map(str.lower, x)).most_common(1)[0][1])
)
print(df[x[0] > 1])
```

Prints:

```
   Year                           Title
1  2021  Energy calculation with energy
```

Comment: if multiple values in list this failed.

Comment: @jezrael I've edited it, but your solution is more elegant :)

Comment: ya, performance here should be problem.