# merging masked arrays - python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, merge, mask

Ok i've seen similar questions out there to this and have been trying to apply multiple methods. I can not figure out what i'm doing wrong.

I have a function that creates a masked array:

```
def masc(arr,z):
        return(np.ma.masked_where((arr[:,:,2] <= z+0.05)*(arr[:,:,2] >= z-0.05)))
```

where arr is a three dimensional array and z is any value.

I'm working towards iterating this over unique z's, but currently just trialing and erroring running the function with two different z values, and merging the two masked arrays together. The code I have thus far looks like this:

```
masked_array1_1 = masc(xyz,z1)
masked_array1_2 = masc(xyz,z2)

masked_1 = np.logical_and(masked_array1_1.mask,masked_array1_2.mask)
masked_array1 = np.ma.array(xyz,mask=masked_1)
```

I get the following error at the line of code

```
masked_array1 = np.ma.array(xyz,mask = masked_1)
```

Mask and data not compatible: data size is 703125, mask size is 234375.

I personally feel like the error is plain to see but my weak python eyes can't see it. Let me know if i need to provide example arrays.

Comment: Could you expand the one line return function into a normal one, this would really help with legibility. And could you explain what a masked array is supposed to be?

Comment: @Herman the masked array is a three dimensional array in which some elements are masked based on the corresponding z values. Does that answer your question? Sorry i'm not very good at posing questions.

Comment: @hpaulj Do you see what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I presume `def masc` should be like this, right?

```py
def masc(arr,z):
    return np.ma.masked_where((arr[:,:,2] <= z+0.05)*(arr[:,:,2] >= z-0.05), arr[:,:,2])
```

Now coming back to your question: It's because you have `arr[:,:,2]` (and not just `arr`) inside `def masc`. Suppose `xyz` has the shape `(nx, ny, nz)`, then the function that's returned by `masc` has the shape `(nx, ny)`. This does not have the same shape as `xyz`. You can now either set `masked_array1 = np.ma.array(xyz[:,:,2],mask=masked_1)` or remove `[:,:,2]` altogether from everywhere.

Comment: yes thank you! And yes you fixed the way the function was written. I removed some unnecessary information from it and forgot that. Do you know if there is a way to merge more than 2 masked arrays using np.logical?

Comment: Using `np.logical` I don't know, but the same happens if you simply multiply the boolean arrays: `masked_array1_1.mask*masked_array1_2.mask*masked_array1_3.mask` etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528328/numpy-logical-or-for-more-than-two-arguments this actually answered that exact question. Thanks again.