# Same comparison over two DataFrame columns to form a mask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a pandas Dataframe with columns `col1` and `col2`. I am trying to build `col3` as:

```
df["col3"] = (df["col1"] == 1) | (df["col2"] ==1)
```

and it works. I tried to rewrite it as:

```
df["col3"] = any([df[c] == 1 for c in ["col1", "col2"]])
```

but I get the infamous `ValueError: The truth value of a series is ambiguous ...`

I even tried to rewrite `any( .. )` as `pd.Series( .. ).any()`, but it did not work.

How would you do it?

Comment: That's because `df[c] == 1` gives a Series object. You can't convert a Series object to bool. You'd get the same error when you run `bool(df['col1']==1)`. `any` checks if there's any *truthy* value in the iterable.

Comment: *How would you do it?*  The first option is pythonic, idiomatic and vectorized. I'd go with the first one.

Comment: In addition to @Ch3steR statements, result of `any(...)` will be just one boolian! One `True` or one `False`.

Answer (score 0):

SImpliest is compare all columns filtered in list for boolean DataFrame and add [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
(df[["col1", "col2"]] == 1).any(axis=1)
```

Your solution should be changed by [np.logical_or.reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528328/numpy-logical-or-for-more-than-two-arguments/20528566#20528566):

```
np.logical_or.reduce([df[c] == 1 for c in ["col1", "col2"]])
```

Or a bit overcomplicated:

```
pd.concat([df[c] == 1 for c in ["col1", "col2"]], axis=1).any(axis=1)
```

Answer (score -1):

As was already explained in the comments, the `any` function implicitly tries (and fails) to convert a series to `bool`

If you want to have something similar to your second code snippet, you can use numpy's `any` function as this supports only a single axis.

```
import numpy
np.any([df[c] == 1 for c in ["col1", "col2"]], axis=0)
```

Alternatively, you could also extend your first code snippet to more columns by using `reduce`

```
In [6]: import functools
In [7]: functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a | b, [(df[c] == 1) for c in ['col1', 'col2']])
```