# (Python/Pandas) How to automatically filter rows by multiple conditions (perhaps using list comprehension)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, database, filter

I'm using Python 3.7.7 with Pandas 1.1.3.

I have two Pandas databases `df1` and `df2` with **identical column names** which can be listed by `list(df1.columns)` or `list(df2.columns)`. Their length is `len(list(df1.columns)) = 200`.

I would like to look for all rows in `df2` where **the frist 10 values match** the values in the `i`'th row of `df1`.

I am aware this can be done the following way:

```
colnames = list(df1.columns[:10]) # lists the first 10 column names
toFind = list(df1.iloc[i][:10]) # lists the first 10 values in the i'th row of df1
df2.loc[(df2[colnames[0]] == toFind[0]) & (df2[colnames[1]] == toFind[1]) & (df2[colnames[2]] == toFind[2]) & (df2[colnames[3]] == toFind[3]) & (df2[colnames[4]] == toFind[4]) & (df2[colnames[5]] == toFind[5]) & (df2[colnames[6]] == toFind[6]) & (df2[colnames[7]] == toFind[7]) & (df2[colnames[8]] == toFind[8]) & (df2[colnames[9]] == toFind[9])]
```

However this is extremely long and difficult to change. If I want to filter by a different number of matching indices (other than 10), I'd have to rewrite the whole expression every time.

Is there a way to do this automatically? I'm looking for something like

```
colnames = list(df1.columns[:10])
toFind = list(df1.iloc[i][:10])
df2.loc[(df2[colnames[t]] == toFind[t]) for t in range(len(colnames))]
```

However this obviously returns an error, as nothing like this is implemented in Pandas.

**Example:** (for simplicity's sake, I'll use 3 instead of 10, and set `i=0`)

```
df1:

i  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
0     1     7     3     4     8     2     4
1     2     5     7     1     4     8     2
2     6     6     8     8     9     1     3
3     7     8     5     2     3     0     9
4     4     0     7     4     5     6     3 
5     2     7     6     8     1     7     5

df2:

i  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
0     1     7     3     3     3     4     5
1     2     5     7     5     5     2     5
2     1     7     3     6     6     4     2
3     3     5     7     7     7     6     4
4     1     7     3     8     8     2     3 
5     2     5     7     3     9     0     6
```

Then I would like to select all rows of `df2` where the first 3 values are `1 7 3` (same as the first 3 values of the `0`th row of `df1`). That would be

```
filtered df2 (0):

i  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
0     1     7     3     3     3     4     5
2     1     7     3     6     6     4     2
4     1     7     3     8     8     2     3
```

As you can see, it filtered for the rows of `df2`, where the first 3 values are `1 7 3`

If instead `i=1`, then I'd like to filter for the rows of `df2`where the first 3 values are `2 5 7` (same as the first 3 values of the `1`st row of `df1`)

In that case, the output would be

```
filtered df2 (1):

i  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
1     2     5     7     5     5     2     5
5     2     5     7     3     9     0     6
```

The aforementioned 3, that controls which columns I filter by is also a parameter, in the previous example, it controled `col1 col2 col3`, and in my first explanation it was 10, it controled `col1 col2 ... col10`

In general, it could be any list of the columns, for example `[col5 col7 col8 col15]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.logical_and.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20528328/2901002):

```
i = 0
colnames = list(df1.columns[:3])
toFind = list(df1.iloc[i][:3])

mask = np.logical_and.reduce([(df2[colnames[t]]==toFind[t]) for t in range(len(colnames))])
df = df2[mask]

print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
i                                          
0     1     7     3     3     3     4     5
2     1     7     3     6     6     4     2
4     1     7     3     8     8     2     3
```

Another idea is use:

```
i = 0
colnames = list(df1.columns[:3])
toFind = list(df1.iloc[i][:3])
df = df2[df2[colnames].eq(toFind).all(axis=1)]

print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7
i                                          
0     1     7     3     3     3     4     5
2     1     7     3     6     6     4     2
4     1     7     3     8     8     2     3
```

Comment: The part with `df1[toFind]` gives me an error, because `len(toFind) = 10`, while the number of columns in `df1` is 200, and the remaining 190 columns aren't specified.

`KeyError: "None of [Index(['col1','col2',...,'col10'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: Okay, well, the most recent edit does output something, however it doesn't contain row `i` of `df1`, how do I filter for that most easily?

Comment: @DanielP - Can you post some sample data with expected ouput? Loop is necessary?

Comment: Okay, I'll edit my main post with an example. Give me a minute.

Comment: Added an example. Hopefully my question is clearer now.

Comment: @DanielP - answer was edited.

Comment: On second thought, the second idea also works. Obviously you cna change `toFind` there as well. My bad.