# Filter of one dataframe using multiple columns of other dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements

I have one dataframe(df1) which is my raw data from which i want to filter or extract a part of the data. I have another dataframe(df2) which have my filter conditions. The catch here is my filter condition column if blank should skip tht column condition and move to the other column conditions

Example below:

**DF1:**

| City | District | Town | Country | Continent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY | WASHIN | DC | US | America |
| CZCH | SEATLLE | DC | CZCH | Europe |
| NY | MARYLAND | DC | US | S America |
| NY | WASHIN | NY | US | America |
| NY | SEAGA | NJ | UK | Europe |

**DF2:**(sample filter condition table - this table can have multiple conditions)

| City | District | Town | Country | Continent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY |  | DC |  |  |
|  |  | NJ |  |  |

Notice that i have left the district, country and continent column blank. As I may or may not use it later. I cannot delete these columns.

**OUTPUT DF:** should look like this

| City | District | Town | Country | Continent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY | WASHIN | DC | US | America |
| NY | MARYLAND | DC | US | S America |
| NY | SEAGA | NJ | UK | Europe |

So basically i need a filter condition table which will extract information from the raw data for fields i input in the filter tables. I cannot change/delete columns in DF2. I can only leave the column blank if i dont require the filter condition.

Thanks in advance,
Nitz

Comment: in `DF2` is multiple rows?

Comment: yes..it can have multiple rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `DF2` has always one row:

```
df = df1.merge(df2.dropna(axis=1))
print (df)
  City District Town Country  Continent
0   NY   WASHIN   DC      US    America
1   NY       NJ   DC      US  S America
```

If multiple rows with missing values:

Sample data:

```
nan = np.nan
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['NY', 'CZCH', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY'], 'District': ['WASHIN', 'SEATLLE', 'MARYLAND', 'WASHIN', 'SEAGA'], 'Town': ['DC', 'DC', 'DC', 'NY', 'NJ'], 'Country': ['US', 'CZCH', 'US', 'US', 'UK'], 'Continent': ['America', 'Europe', 'S America', 'America', 'Europe']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'City': ['NY', nan], 'District': [nan, nan], 'Town': ['DC', 'NJ'], 'Country': [nan, nan], 'Continent': [nan, nan]})
```

First remove missing values with reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print (df2.stack())
0  City    NY
   Town    DC
1  Town    NJ
dtype: object
```

Then for each group compare `df1` columns if exist in columns names and value from `df2`:

```
m = [df1[list(v.droplevel(0).index)].eq(v.droplevel(0)).all(axis=1)
      for k, v in df2.stack().groupby(level=0)]


print (m)
[0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool, 0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool]
```

Use [`logical_or.reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528566/2901002) and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (np.logical_or.reduce(m))
[ True False  True False  True]

df = df1[np.logical_or.reduce(m)]
print (df)
  City  District Town Country  Continent
0   NY    WASHIN   DC      US    America
2   NY  MARYLAND   DC      US  S America
4   NY     SEAGA   NJ      UK     Europe
```

Comment: No.. it will have multiple rows with various conditions

Comment: @Ningkontan - Can you test now? empty valeus are missing `NaN`s ?

Comment: Are 'k' and 'v' dummy variables..is it possible if you can explain how it works?

Comment: not missing NaNs. columns deliberately left empty...will try the solution suggested and get back

Comment: @jezrael...Got this error.. 
`chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 805, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory    
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 861, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows 
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1952, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error       
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 258104: invalid start byte`

Comment: @Ningkontan - Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18172249/2901002)

Comment: Just tried it..only one filter worked the rest did not. so the logic should be filter first for all data with 'NY',x,y,z as city then from this subset, filter with DC,a,b,c as town.. and so on....Is it possible to do a column by column sequential filtering...... and if a column does not have any value just ignore them..

Comment: @Ningkontan - Can you change data sample? Because not sure if understand what need.

Comment: have increased the size of sample data for more clarity

Comment: @Ningkontan - Do you try example data with my solution? for me working perfectly.

Comment: @Ningkontan - added your data to answer - all working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, using [`numpy broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) (it works even when `df2` has more than one row):

```
df1.loc[np.sum(np.sum(
        df1.values == df2.values[:, None], axis=2) == 
    np.sum(df2.notna().values, axis=1)[:,None], axis=0) == 1]
```

Output:

```
  City  District Town Country  Continent
0   NY    WASHIN   DC      US    America
2   NY  MARYLAND   DC      US  S America
4   NY     SEAGA   NJ      UK     Europe
```

Comment: Got this error `  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in sum
  File "C:\python\pyver\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2298, in sum
    return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
  File "C:\python\pyver\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 86, in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
numpy.AxisError: axis 2 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0`

Comment: I cannot find a good explanation for your error: Are you running the latest `numpy` version? I have just tried with your new data, and it works perfectly on my computer.